# beamer & TikZ: gradually unveil trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, trees

Imagine a simple tree:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {Selbstregulation}
    [edge from parent fork down]
    child {node {Kognition}}
    child {node {Metakognition}
      child {node {Planung}}
      child {node {Monotoring}}
      child {node {Regulation}}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is it possible to unveil the child nodes step by step using overlays in beamer? I tried with the `\onslide` command at several positions around `child`, but it doesn't work...

Any hints? - Thanks.

Comment: Well, take a look at this solution of the problem: http://old.nabble.com/successive-creation-of-tikz-mindmap-in-beamer-td22478489.html#a22522788 it seems to be not as easy as it should be, but doable...

Comment: Consider reading this QA http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117309/step-by-step-revealing-of-tikz-tree-using-opacity-trick-and-overlays-in-beamer

Answer (score 10):

A TikZ option to set the color to white depending on the current slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{hide on/.code={\only<#1>{\color{white}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \only<4>{} % Force beamer to show the correct amount of slides
    \node {Selbstregulation}
    [edge from parent fork down]
    child {node {Kognition}}
    child {node  {Metakognition}
      child [hide on=-2]  {node {Planung}}
      child [hide on=-3] {node {Monotoring}}
      child [hide on=1] {node {Regulation}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Placing the `[hide on=..]` option to get the right effect is a bit tricky. For example, the downward line is always drawn with the last child, so that node has to be uncovered first.

(Also note that the `\tikzset` has to be called outside the `frame`s (I guess for reasons of catcode trickery).)

Comment: Maybe it’s better to change the opacity to `0` instead of setting the color to withe, because the latter will keep visible on backgrounds with different colors (e.g. gradients or images). I didn’t test it so I’m not sure if it works …

Answer (score 4):

[I have been told this is not possible](http://osdir.com/ml/tex.latex.beamer.general/2007-02/msg00029.html).  [The package author wrote in 2005 that it wasn't](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.latex.beamer.general/432).  If the ability has been added I do not know of it.

My correspondent's advice is the best workaround that I can think of:

> To get the same effect, you may want
>   to try drawing the final figure and
>   then work backwards, making this
>   invisible by making them have the same
>   color as the background or
>   transparent.

Comment: Thanks. To get it clear: you are suggesting that I should create the whole tree and copy-paste the picture on the preceding frames making the corresponding transparency changes? The problem here is that the connection lines beween the nodes remain visible, if set a node to be transparent...

Comment: @Fred: To hide individual nodes, you can use `{\only<2->{Planung}}` for the node text.

Answer (score 1):

I improved the answer of Caramdir using opacity instead of color white, changing:

```
\tikzset{hide on/.code={\only<#1>{\color{white}}}}
```

with:

```
\tikzset{hide on/.code={\only<#1>{\color{fg!20}}}}
```

in my case I wanted a semitransparent effect, you can also set "fg!0" for full hiding, or any other level of opacity.

the full code is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{hide on/.code={\only<#1>{\color{fg!20}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \only<4>{} % Force beamer to show the correct amount of slides
    \node {Selbstregulation}
    [edge from parent fork down]
    child {node {Kognition}}
    child {node  {Metakognition}
      child [hide on=-2]  {node {Planung}}
      child [hide on=-3] {node {Monotoring}}
      child [hide on=1] {node {Regulation}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a very similar approach to [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/13304) :)