# Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, mindmaps

I want to include a `tikzpicture` (mindmap) in `beamer` and I want the children to appear one after the other.

So I use `\visible` but it don't works -- also not with `\pause` command. I get errors regarding forgotten semicolons. When I insert semicolons, not all of the mindmap is created.

Is there an easy way to realize that?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Charakteristika}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, concept color=gray!50, font=\sf, text=white]

  \tikzstyle{level 1 concept}+=[font=\sf, sibling angle=90,level distance = 30mm]

 \visible<1->{
  \node[concept,scale=0.7] {Gedächtnis}
    [clockwise from=135]}
      \visible<2->{
        child[concept color=orange]{ node[concept,scale=0.7]{Musik} } }
      \visible<3->{
        child[concept color=orange]{ node[concept,scale=0.7]{Kunst} } }
      \visible<4->{
        child[concept color=orange]{ node[concept,scale=0.7]{Mathematik} } }
      \visible<5->{
        child[concept color=orange]{ node[concept,scale=0.7]{Seltenere} } };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of there's yet a "proper" way to do this, but I've had good results with [Matthew Leingang's very general solution in a previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155/4535). This allows you to arbitrarily change properties per slide, color being the obvious target here. There may be some more hints in [this previous thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9094/beamer-vs-tikz-uncover-nodes-step-by-step) as well.

Comment: I think you should use `\uncover` instead of `\visible`.

Comment: @kgr: Sorry, but I converted your post to a comment, because links to answers do not qualify as new answers. You could however add a full solution based on these answers. Simply edit and undelete your post.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

> This answer has led to the [aobs-tikz](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) package by Claudio Fiandrino, which provides extended versions of the concepts below.

Here is a less hacky alternative to the answer given by Claudio:

In conjunction with TikZ, I have almost stopped completely to use beamer's overlay commands (`\visible<>`, `\only<>`, and so on). Instead I *always* draw all elements, but hide them on the slides they should not appear. To specify the visibility, I use a `visible on=<...>` TikZ style as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shadows}
\begin{document}

  % Keys to support piece-wise uncovering of elements in TikZ pictures:
  % \node[visible on=<2->](foo){Foo}
  % \node[visible on=<{2,4}>](bar){Bar}   % put braces around comma expressions
  %
  % Internally works by setting opacity=0 when invisible, which has the 
  % adavantage (compared to \node<2->(foo){Foo} that the node is always there, hence
  % always consumes space plus that coordinate (foo) is always available.
  %
  % The actual command that implements the invisibility can be overriden
  % by altering the style invisible. For instance \tikzsset{invisible/.style={opacity=0.2}}
  % would dim the "invisible" parts. Alternatively, the color might be set to white, if the
  % output driver does not support transparencies (e.g., PS) 
  %
  \tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Charakteristika}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, concept color=gray!50, font=\sf, text=white]

  \tikzstyle{level 1 concept}+=[font=\sf, sibling angle=90,level distance = 30mm]

  \node[concept,scale=0.7] {Gedächtnis}
    [clockwise from=135]
        child[concept color=orange, visible on=<2->]{ node[concept,scale=0.7]{Musik} } 
        child[concept color=orange, visible on=<3->]{ node[concept,scale=0.7]{Kunst} } 
        child[concept color=orange, visible on=<4->]{ node[concept,scale=0.7]{Mathematik} } 
        child[concept color=orange, visible on=<5->]{ node[concept,scale=0.7]{Seltenere} };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`visible on=< ovspec >` is implemented by applying the style `invisible` on all slides that are not contained in *ovspec*. The default implementation of `invisible` just sets `opacity=0`; however, this can be overwritten, so other kinds of "invsibility" can easily be installed (dimming, gray filling, ...).

**Note:** If *overspec* itself contains a comma, either it or the complete argument has to be put inside curly braces (like in, `visible on=<{1,3-4,8}>` or `visible on={<1,3-4,8>}`) in order to not confuse the pgfkeys parser.

This approach (besides being, IMHO, much better readable) also has another advantage: All named elements (especially nodes) are always there, so you can use them for coordinate calculations even on slides they are not visible. Moreover, the `tikzpicture` always has the complete size, preventing the frequently asked issue of "jumping images".

[image: animation]

Comment: @Dave: `tikz` and `transparent` probably clash in the backend driver.  There have been some [reported issues](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/tikzdevice-bugs/2011-September/000230.html) of using `transparent` and the `opacity` feature of `tikz` in conjunction. However, TikZ should provide you all the transparency features you ever need.

Comment: @Daniel: Ah, it was that simple?? I introduced some new styles `visible2 on=...` that would then convert spaces into commas. -_- Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @Daniel: Actually, `visible on={<1,3>}` didn't work, but `visible on=<{1,3}>` did. =)

Comment: @gablin: Right, it has to be that way, as obvious from the delimited argument specification. I have now edited this into the answer.

Comment: nice indeed. Is there a way to get it working with externalization (I'm using `\usepgfplotslibrary{external} \tikzexternalize`)?

Comment: Christian Feuersänger's [solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79461/78282) works when using `\tikzexternalize`

Comment: @Daniel I have a question. I have the nodes of a tree linked together with the command `[edge from parent fork down]`. But I want those edges be visible when I want. I can make disappear the vertices with the command `visible on`, but I cannot get rid of the edges. I want the edges appearing not necesseray at the same time at the vertices. I tried  `[edge from parent fork down, visible on = ]` but all the tree disappears at the same time. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Daniel I posted it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436389/overlay-of-edges-of-a-tree-created-with-one-command)

Answer (score 19):

Here is a solution taken from [this message](http://old.nabble.com/Re:-successive-creation-of-tikz-mindmap-in-beamer-p22516097.html) and adapted to your need (just 1 level, clockwise option and position of concepts angle 90, but you will see that I commented the code where there is something taken from your needs).

**Edit**: seen now that I forgot the `text=white`; I will add a comment only in the place you should modify.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shadows}

\begin{document}

% excellent code taken from 
% http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A-successive-creation-of-tikz-mindmap-in-beamer-p22516097.html
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@collect@child
hild{\pgfutil@ifnextchar<{\tikz@collect@child@overlay}{\tikz@collect@childA}}
\def\tikz@collect@child@overlay<#1>{%
        \pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tikz@collect@child@@overlay{#1}}{\tikz@collect@childA[child
overlay={#1}]}}%}

\def\tikz@collect@child@@overlay#1[{\tikz@collect@childA[child overlay={#1},}

\def\tikzprocessoverlay#1#2#3{%
        \def\beamer@doifinframe{#2}%
        \def\beamer@doifnotinframe{#3}%
        \beamer@masterdecode{#1}%
        \beamer@donow%
}

% Extra hackery to allow preactions on different layers.
%
\def\tikz@extra@preaction#1{%
  {%
    \pgfsys@beginscope%
      \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\voidb@x%
      \begingroup\tikzset{#1}\expandafter\endgroup%
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@preaction@layer\expandafter{\tikz@preaction@layer}%
      \ifx\tikz@preaction@layer\pgfutil@empty%
      \path[#1];% do extra path
      \else%
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{\tikz@preaction@layer}%
      \path[#1];%
      \end{pgfonlayer}
      \fi%
      \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\tikz@actions@path% restore
      \tikz@restorepathsize%
    \pgfsys@endscope%
  }%
}
\let\tikz@preaction@layer=\pgfutil@empty

\tikzset{preaction layer/.store in=\tikz@preaction@layer}

\makeatother

\tikzset{%
        child overlay/.code={%
                \tikzprocessoverlay{#1}{}%
                {%
                        \tikzset{%
                                circle connection bar switch color/.code={},
                                edge from parent/.style={draw=none},
                                every node/.style={
                                        concept, draw=none, fill=none,
                                        execute at begin node={\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\hskip0pt\let\\=\relax},
                                        execute at end node=\egroup\phantom{\box0}
                                }%
                        }%
                }%
        }
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{shadow}
\pgfsetlayers{shadow,main}

\tikzset{
        use shadow/.style={%
                copy shadow={%
                        preaction layer=shadow, fill=gray!25, draw=none,
                        shadow xshift=0.5ex, shadow yshift=-0.5ex
                }
        },
        small mindmap/.style={
          level 1/.append style={level 1 concept},
          concept color=gray!50, % root colored in gray
          every concept/.style={align=center, font=\tiny\strut, text=black,% <= TEXT COLOR CHANGE
outer sep=-.25pt}, 
          text width=2cm,
          level 1 concept/.style={
          % font \sf as seen in your example
          font=\sf,
          text width=1.5cm,
          level distance=3cm,
          % some modifications to require needs
          sibling angle=90,
          clockwise from=135,
          every child/.style={concept color=orange},
          },
          every node/.style={concept, execute at begin node=\hskip0pt, use shadow},
          every circle connection bar/.append style={append after
command={[use shadow]}}
        }
}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Charakteristika}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, small mindmap]
\node <1->  {Gedächtnis}
                        child <2-> {node {Musik}}
                        child <3-> {node {Kunst}}
                        child <4->{node {Mathematik}}
                        child <5->{node {Seltenere}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I show just three frames over the five generated:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It's definitely not easy, but in principle it works. Only, when I try this, that is shifted over the left border. But it's not a problem because Daniel give a helpful solution too.

Comment: Yes, you are right; the problem could be fixed by compiling twice.