# tikzpicture in Beamer: how to uncover nodes in foreach statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

How can I uncover the nodes in the following tikzpicture? I want to display all red nodes, followed by all green nodes, and then followed by all blue nodes.

```
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling angle=120]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling angle=60]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling angle=30]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt]
\tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[segment length=1mm,
                          segment angle=10,draw] 
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow cyclic,shape=circle,very thick,level distance=13mm,
                cap=round,scale=0.5]
\node {} child [color=\A] foreach \A in {red,red,red}
{  node {} child [color=\A!50!\B] foreach \B in {green,green,green}
     { node {} child [color=\A!50!\B!50!\C] foreach \C in {blue,blue,blue}
         { node {} }
    }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. See e.g. [Should `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/2975)

Comment: @PeterGrill: Thanks for the note. I would provide MWE for my questions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In this solution I applied the Daniel's method shown in [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/tikzpicture-in-beamer): it has several advantages and it is very simple to be used.

In the following code, with respect to the MWE provided, I shifted in the preamble the style definitions:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,decorations}
\usetheme{EastLansing}

% style definitions
\tikzset{level 1/.style={sibling angle=120}}
\tikzset{level 2/.style={sibling angle=60}}
\tikzset{level 3/.style={sibling angle=30}}
\tikzset{every node/.style={fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt}}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={segment length=1mm,
                          segment angle=10,draw}}

% Daniel's code:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/tikzpicture-in-beamer/55827#55827
  \tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow cyclic,shape=circle,very thick,level distance=13mm,
                cap=round,scale=0.5]
\node {} child [color=\A,visible on=<1->] foreach \A in {red,red,red}
{  node {} child [color=\A!50!\B,visible on=<2->] foreach \B in {green,green,green}
     { node {} child [color=\A!50!\B!50!\C,visible on=<3->] foreach \C in {blue,blue,blue}
         { node {} }
    }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What you simply have to do, once inserted in the preamble the Daniel's code, is to define in which time instant you want to display nodes; the method is to add in `child` options `visible on=<...>`.

Finally, what you get are those three frames:

[image]

Comment: A really cool feature of this approach is that you can even use `visible on=<\slide->` in a `\foreach \slide in {...}` loop. This is also not possible with the standard TikZ syntax.