# Change the pagenumbering in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

In my beamer presentation I build a picture over some frames. But I want the pagenumber to stay while the picture is build up.

Is there something similar to `\section*{Sectionname}`, or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You might want to look at the overlay commands provided by `beamer`, e.g. `\onslide`, `\only`, and `\visible`.

Comment: Have a look for example to [Get a includegraphic to stick in the same place for several beamer slides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82369/get-a-includegraphic-to-stick-in-the-same-place-for-several-beamer-slides) in case you are inserting different images or to [tikzpicture in Beamer: how to uncover nodes in foreach statement](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56582/tikzpicture-in-beamer-how-to-uncover-nodes-in-foreach-statement) if your image is built with TikZ.

Comment: Thank you both. The \only-command did what I wanted to achieve :-)

Comment: @Dave: if you solved the problem, this question should be probably closed as too localized.