# Appearance of tikz node on key press or mouse click

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Considering the following TeX code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (A) [draw=blue] {Text1};
      \node (B) [draw=yellow] {Text2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can one put a pause after the appearance of node 'A' and 
at any key press or mouse click, node 'B' should appear.

Comment: You can use `\only<1>{\node (A) [draw=blue] {Text1};}` and `\only<2>{\node (B) [draw=blue] {Text2};}`.

Comment: As an alternative, see [tikzpicture in Beamer: how to uncover nodes in foreach statement](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56582/13304).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `\pause` normally:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (A) [draw=blue] {Text1};
      \pause
      \node (B) [draw=yellow, below of=A] {Text2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have placed node `B` below node `A`, whereas you had them on top of each other.

[image]