# Addressing overlay specifications in TikZ-pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, mindmaps

I was creating a mindmap for a presentation using as reference [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/tikzpicture-in-beamer#55849). My code is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
  },
}

\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=90,level distance = 25mm}}
\tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=0.6,text=white}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,text=white, concept color=blue]
\node[concept,visible on=<1->]{Root Concept}[clockwise from=315]
 child [concept color=violet,visible on=<2,3>] {node[concept] (c1){Child 1}                                
 }
 child [concept color=orange,visible on=<3>]{node [concept](c2){Child 2}
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which causes as error:

```
! Argument of \pgfkeys@code has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.38 \end{frame}
```

I suspect the problem arises along the line:

```
child [concept color=violet,visible on=<2,3>] {node[concept] (c1){Child 1}}
```

in particular in presence of `<2,3>` (simply writing `<2>` or `<2->` the compilation is fine), but I don't see any way to fix it and even (worst) I don't understand the reasons behind this error.

Comment: `<3-4>` works, too.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: yes.. also in this way it works. Thanks `:)`

Comment: This is hardly a minimal example. I've been playing with it and have been able to remove several statements and still reproduce the same error. In the interest of saving other people's time, I suggest you trim this down as best as you can.

Comment: A simple rule to use pgfkeys: It is permissible to surround both the key or the value in curly braces (which are removed). Especially putting the value in curly braces needs to be done quite often, namely whenever the value contains an **equal-sign** or a **comma**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With

```
child  [concept color=violet,visible on=<{3,4}>] {node [concept](c13){Child 1-3}}
```

Your code runs fine.

Comment: Oh.. that's right, it works! It didn't come in my mind. Thank you very much `:)`