# Tikzpicture highlight on matrix in different slides

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles

I am new to latex but I have to make a presentation in university with it (or more I want to do the presentation in LaTeX). But I am struggling with the package `tikz`.

1. So my first question is regarding the on statement which can not handle something like `<1-3, 5-6>`, which is possible like in only statements. Is there a work around?
2. Second question is about the highlight style is it possible to set different styles on different slides like highlight text on=`<1-3>` and something else, text on=`<5-6>`?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles, matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  background default text=black,
  highlight/.style={
    background text=blue,
    },
  ]
\matrix [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&]{
|[highlight, text on=<1->]| . \& |[highlight, text on=<2->]| X \\
. \&  X\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please change your latex code to a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: First question: is it working too, but you have to protect the argument with braces, see [Addressing overlay specifications in TikZ-pictures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74201/13304).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's possible using the built-in capabilities of the `overlay-beamer-styles` library, but I can achieve this using the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155/21344) from [How to make beamer overlays with Tikz node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6135/21344):

```
\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} 
}}
```

creates the possibility of usage like

```
onslide=<1-2>highlight
```

to apply the `highlight` style for overlays 1 and 2. These `onslide=` constructs are stackable, as shown in the example below.

The definition of `\overlaynumber` is from [Accessing the current overlay number in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55058/21344) and is just used for this example to display the current overlay number for illustration purposes.

As mentioned in comments here and at Matthew's answer, if the overlay specification contains commas, the whole construct must be encapsulated in curly braces. (Illustrated with `onslide={<4,6-8>cyan}` here.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles, matrix}

\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55066/21344
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} 
}} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155/21344

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  background default text=black,
  highlight/.style={
    background text=blue,
    },
   laterhilite/.style={
    background text=red,
    },
  ]
\matrix [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&]{
|[highlight, text on=<{1-}>]| . \& 
|[onslide=<1-2>highlight,
  onslide=<3->laterhilite,
  onslide={<4,6-8>cyan},
 ]|   X\\
. \&  X\\
\overlaynumber \&  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may use `<1-2>highlight` instead of `<1-2>{highlight}` (and so on...). The arguments of `.code args` are delimited (by the comma).