# How can I make Beamer overlays with TikZ node attributes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, tikz-styles, animations

As a follow-up question to [Tikz animated figure in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136143/17423), how can I animate a particular attribute of a node?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\tikzset{
  node distance = 3 cm,
  graph vertex/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=7.5mm,
  },
  marked/.style={
    color=white,
    fill=black,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[graph vertex, marked] (1) at (0 , 3) {$v_1$};
      \node[graph vertex,       ] (2) at (0 , 6) {$v_2$};
      \node[graph vertex,       ] (3) at (3 , 3) {$v_3$};
      \node[graph vertex, marked] (4) at (3 , 6) {$v_4$};
      \node[graph vertex,       ] (5) at (5 , 8) {$v_5$};

      \graph {
        (1) -- (3) -- (4) -- (2) --[bend left] (5),
        (1) -- (2),
        (1) -- (4),
        (3) --[bend right] (5)
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[graph vertex, marked] (1) at (0 , 3) {$v_1$};
      \node[graph vertex,       ] (2) at (0 , 6) {$v_2$};
      \node[graph vertex,       ] (3) at (3 , 3) {$v_3$};
      \node[graph vertex, marked] (4) at (3 , 6) {$v_4$};
      \node[graph vertex, marked] (5) at (5 , 8) {$v_5$};

      \graph {
        (1) -- (3) -- (4) -- (2) --[bend left] (5),
        (1) -- (2),
        (1) -- (4),
        (3) --[bend right] (5)
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[graph vertex, marked] (1) at (0 , 3) {$v_1$};
      \node[graph vertex,       ] (2) at (0 , 6) {$v_2$};
      \node[graph vertex,       ] (3) at (3 , 3) {$v_3$};
      \node[graph vertex,       ] (4) at (3 , 6) {$v_4$};
      \node[graph vertex, marked] (5) at (5 , 8) {$v_5$};

      \graph {
        (1) -- (3) -- (4) -- (2) --[bend left] (5),
        (1) -- (2),
        (1) -- (4),
        (3) --[bend right] (5)
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to get this syntax to something like

```
\begin{frame}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[graph vertex, marked      ] (1) at (0 , 3) {$v_1$};
      \node[graph vertex,             ] (2) at (0 , 6) {$v_2$};
      \node[graph vertex,             ] (3) at (3 , 3) {$v_3$};
      \node[graph vertex, marked=<1-2>] (4) at (3 , 6) {$v_4$};
      \node[graph vertex, marked=<2-3>] (5) at (5 , 8) {$v_5$};

      \graph {
        (1) -- (3) -- (4) -- (2) --[bend left] (5),
        (1) -- (2),
        (1) -- (4),
        (3) --[bend right] (5)
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

I'm open to other syntax options as well, as long as it 'more or less' adheres to the above (i.e. doesn't duplicate code, is readable).

#### Attempt with `overlay-beamer-styles`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\tikzset{
  node distance = 3 cm,
  graph vertex/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=7.5mm,
  },
  marked/.style={
    color=white,
    fill=black,
  },
  marked on/.style={alt=#1{}{marked}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[graph vertex, marked         ] (1) at (0 , 3) {$v_1$};
      \node[graph vertex,                ] (2) at (0 , 6) {$v_2$};
      \node[graph vertex,                ] (3) at (3 , 3) {$v_3$};
      \node[graph vertex, marked on=<1-2>] (4) at (3 , 6) {$v_4$};
      \node[graph vertex, marked on=<2-3>] (5) at (5 , 8) {$v_5$};

      \graph {
        (1) -- (3) -- (4) -- (2) --[bend left] (5),
        (1) -- (2),
        (1) -- (4),
        (3) --[bend right] (5)
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can have a look to the `aobs-tikz` package: it allows, for instance, to change shading, filling, or even make double the border of a node with the syntax you were proposing.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino This looks promising, thanks for uploading it! I can't seem to get the syntax right though; I've edited-in a buggy attempt to get it working.

Comment: unfortunately, at the moment I can't answer; I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code using `overlay-beamer-styles` will work if you change the code line

```
  marked on/.style={alt=#1{}{marked}},
```

to

```
  marked on/.style={alt=#1{marked}{}},
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\tikzset{
  node distance = 3 cm,
  graph vertex/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=7.5mm,
  },
  marked/.style={
    color=white,
    fill=black,
  },
  marked on/.style={alt=#1{marked}{}},
}

\makeatletter
\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test slide \arabic{slideinframe}}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[graph vertex, marked         ] (1) at (0 , 3) {$v_1$};
      \node[graph vertex,                ] (2) at (0 , 6) {$v_2$};
      \node[graph vertex,                ] (3) at (3 , 3) {$v_3$};
      \node[graph vertex, marked on=<1-2>] (4) at (3 , 6) {$v_4$};
      \node[graph vertex, marked on=<2-3>] (5) at (5 , 8) {$v_5$};

      \graph {
        (1) -- (3) -- (4) -- (2) --[bend left] (5),
        (1) -- (2),
        (1) -- (4),
        (3) --[bend right] (5)
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I might be going crazy, but what is the difference between the two snippets you first give?  (Also, you should see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175232)

Comment: @SeanAllred In the first answer I accidentally pasted at the end a version I had designed without using Claudio's library (which I didn't know before this answer); then I removed that version since the code using the library simplifies.

Comment: +1: yesterday I couldn't post an answer (home laptop is not running yet TikZ 3.0.0 ;)), but this is even better that what I had in mind. It demonstrates how to create new styles, something I did not considered, but it has a potential to simplify a lot the code with respect to [How to overlay tikz matrix in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153820/13304) for example.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I didn't know your library before this post. Really nice! However, using something like `\node[graph vertex, marked on=<2-3,5-7>] (5) at (5 , 8) {$v_5$};` in the example code will trigger an error: `Runaway argument?
\pgfkeys@mainstop \def \pgfkeysdefaultpath {/}\ifx \tikz@node@content \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfkeys@code.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> a.tex`. Is not possible to give more complex overlay specifications?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: it is, but I think you have to protect the argument with braces if there are commas (same issue I was asking in [Addressing overlay specifications in TikZ-pictures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74201/13304).