# Access relative slide number in Beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

Is there a quick way to access the relative slide number in Beamer?
I'm trying to simplify the following syntax:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $
   t = \only<1> 0
       \only<2> 1
       \only<3> 2
  $
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be interested in this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer?rq=1 In your case a simple + would do

Comment: @bloodworks Yes, that would work, but it still has me repeating code.  (Although it's certainly possible that such a counter is never kept.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value is stored in `\beamer@slideinframe`; you can use this to define either a counter or a user command to have easy access to it (it was not clear to me what you wanted to do with the slide number in your example, so I use here another simple example):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\def\beamerslideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide \arabic{slideinframe}}
\only<1>{A}
\only<2>{B}
\only<3>{C}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]