# Accessing the current frame number in beamer

Tags: beamer, counters

I know how to manually reset the page counter using a fix value. In the MWE below this fix value `0`. Now I wonder how to use a variable value like `\framenumber - 1`. In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55058/accessing-the-current-overlay-number-in-beamer) it was asked for the counter of the overlay with the solution `\overlaynumber`; but `\framenumber` is an "unidentified controll sequence". Reading [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175232/access-relative-slide-number-in-beamer) I experimented with `\beamer@slideinframe` and `\arabic{slideinframe}` finding, that the latter will always give the same number, and does not increases when called later in the document.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Counter should be 1}
\end{frame}
\setcounter{framenumber}{0}
\begin{frame}{Counter should again be 1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Counter should be 2}
\end{frame}
\setcounter{framenumber}{1}
\begin{frame}{Counter should again be 2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}`? Or if you want frames no not contribute to the framenumbering you could use `noframenumbering` as optional argument

Comment: I posted a few possible approaches

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3 different possibilities how not to increase the frame counter from one page to the next:

**Excluding a frame from contributing to the frame counter**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Counter should be 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Counter should again be 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Counter should be 2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Counter should again be 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Manually adjusting the frame counter**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Counter should be 1}
\end{frame}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\begin{frame}{Counter should again be 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Counter should be 2}
\end{frame}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\begin{frame}{Counter should again be 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Not using different frames**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle<1>{Counter should be 1}
\frametitle<2>{Counter should again be 1}
\only<1>{slide 1}
\only<2>{slide 2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle<1>{Counter should be 2}
\frametitle<2>{Counter should again be 2}
\only<1>{slide 1}
\only<2>{slide 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}` is different to what I expected, but it solved my issue.

Comment: Albeit a long-term heavy beamer user, the `noframenumbering` option is new to me. Seems to be way more elegant than my current fiddling with `framenumber`.

Comment: @Daniel This option was there for a long time but just recently made it into the documentation :)

Comment: @Daniel https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/77f4522628f54616aa403082ee8c132101da0f3c

Comment: Oh, it’s just two months old? I will forgive myself 

Comment: @Daniel Good plan! :)