# Combining beamer, tikz, externalize and standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, tikz-external, standalone

I've read a bunch of questions and answers on these topics as well as the documentation of the `external` library for `tikz`. I suspect I fundamentally misunderstand what I'm doing.

I have a mindmap which I'm including in a `beamer` presentation. It takes forever to compile so I would like to externalise it using the `external` library. I am also using overlay specifications to gradually make parts of the map visible. The mindmap is prepared in a separate file which I `\input` with the facilities of `standalone`.

Without externalisation, my code produces the slides OK. With externalisation, it fails.

This is a Minimal Non-Working Example using `beamer`, `external` and `standalone`. The beamer presentation is in `prawf3.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\makeatletter
    \tikzset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79572/39222
      beamer externalising/.style={%
        execute at end picture={%
          \tikzifexternalizing{%
            \ifbeamer@anotherslide
            \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
            \fi
          }{}%
        }%
      },
      external/optimize=false
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A frame}
    \input{prawf3-pic}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`prawf3-pic.tex` is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[beamer externalising]
        \node (a) {A};
        \only<2->
        \node (b) at (0,1) {B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[Obviously, `prawf3-pic.tex` will not compile on its own as it stands because `beamer externalising` is not defined in that case. This isn't the problem.]

The code for the `beamer externalising` style is from [Andrew Stacey's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79572/39222) to a somewhat similar question which lacked the `standalone` element.

When I try to compile `prawf3.tex` using `pdflatex -shell-escape`, the compilation fails with

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "prawf3-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob
{prawf3}\input{prawf3}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'prawf3-figure0
' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled 
system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is a
lso named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed
? Error messages can be found in 'prawf3-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'l
l try to typeset the picture.
```

but obviously shell escape *is* enabled as the error itself makes clear.

`prawf3-figure0.log` includes this just before it gives up with a `Fatal error` message:

```
LaTeX Info: Redefining \includegraphics on input line 21.
No file prawf3-figure0.nav.
(./prawf3-pic.tex
\openout5 = `prawf3-figure0.dpth'.

Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no B in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!
[1

\providecommand \oddpage@label [2]{}
{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endframe ->\egroup 
                    \begingroup \def \@currenvir {frame}
l.27 \end{frame}
```

I tried using `{}` with `\only<2->`:

```
{\node (b) at (0,1) {B};}
```

but that did not help. (This isn't surprising but it seemed worth trying as it was about the only thing I could think to try.)

Note that I think the complaints about the `nullfont` are unrelated as I get these with the full example even though everything compiles fine.

## EDIT

I'm even more confused now as it turns out that it is not even sufficient to disable externalisation as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzexternaldisable
\makeatletter
    \tikzset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79572/39222
      beamer externalising/.style={%
        execute at end picture={%
          \tikzifexternalizing{%
            \ifbeamer@anotherslide
            \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
            \fi
          }{}%
        }%
      },
      external/optimize=false
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A frame}
    \input{prawf3-pic}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I thought that disabling externalisation would be sufficient to get compilation since it essentially turns the externalisation off. And `beamer externalising` seems to be defined conditionally so that it should be innocuous enough in that case...

Comment: @pluton Do you have this problem? I seem to have figured out how to do this at some point. At least, I certainly externalise TikZ pictures in Beamer now, including ones which use overlay specifications.

Comment: @pluton That is, I don't have a solution in the form of a style, but I have it working generally.

Comment: I was interested in externalizing Tikz figures "within beamer" to be able to use beamer fonts within Tikz figures. If you have a solution, I'm interested. Thanks

Comment: @pluton Sorry. I think all I'm doing is explicitly stating the number of slides to produce per frame. So I'm saying `\begin{frame}<1-2>{Title}...` rather than `\begin{frame}{Title}...`. This does work well, but obviously it is not automatic.

Answer (score 1):

This version works for me (and is shorter in code).

No need for `standalone`. That answer should be possible updated, although my score is yet too low to do that.

If you want full automatization, you would need a counter inside.

**prawf3.tex**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external, automata}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzexternaldisable
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{A frame}
        \input{prawf3-pic}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**prawf3-pic.tex**

```
\only<1-2>{%the count of figures needs to be clear(quick hack)
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (a) {A};
        \only<2->{\node (b) at (0,1) {B};}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Workflow for multiple graphics on slides (possibly in background) and on use of \only or similiar tools or/and on unclear rowing of slides for a long presentation (due to possibly long(er) compilation times)

```
\includegraphics[height=0.65\textheight,keepaspectratio]{tikzGraphics/pdfToInclude}
```

in combination with

```
pdflatex -jobname $jn "\\\documentclass{standalone}\\\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath,ifthen,xcolor}\\\input{../commands.tex}\\\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}\\\input{../plotadaptions.tex}\\\begin{document}\\\input{$file}\\\end{document}"
```

did the job for me.
As complete shell script

```
for file in *.tex 
do
    jn=$(basename -s .tex $file)
    pdflatex -jobname $jn "\\\documentclass{standalone}\\\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath,ifthen,xcolor}\\\input{../commands.tex}\\\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}\\\input{../plotadaptions.tex}\\\begin{document}\\\input{$file}\\\end{document}"
done
```

Only some adaptions to set `tikz`-properties, commands to use and colors are needed and not all PDFs for each slide on changing some graphics need to be compiled.
(This can be very unpleasant on having a 80 slides long presentation)

Comment: Thanks, but my experience obviously differs from yours. Externalising saves compilation time. Enormously. It makes the unmanageable manageable. I can't imagine why you have to wait for compilation to complete before continuing to edit. I have certainly not had that problem. I don't understand how the prefix suggestion is supposed to help. By the way, you don't need `keepaspectratio` in your example. The major disadvantage with your suggestion is, of course, that you have to manually ensure consistency of fonts etc. Externalisation avoids that.

Comment: When you add graphics or slides before the slide to explain stuff, the numbering gets mixed up.
Having background images any inserting of <code>\pause,\only,etc</code> changes the numbering on <code>externalization</code> and everything needs to be compiled again.
For your use case however that might differ and you are correct, if you do not have background images or multiple images on a slide with \only etc.

Comment: No, I often do have multiple images - at least, I often use an image which appears gradually, which amounts to multiple images. And I often use overlay specifications within the `tikzpicture`s for this purpose. I don't generally use changing images as background canvas, though, if that's what you mean.

Comment: The only tricky bit is getting it to work with `handout`. But that's just a question of specifying the number of slides. Annoying, but simple enough.