# combining forest externalization with beamer overlays

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, forest, externalize

The answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274099/77582) for revealing a `forest` tree in beamer bottom-up works beautifully. But it appears to be incompatible with externalization. The following example successfully compiles (with `--shell-escape` switched on), but the resulting pdf is just one slide: the slides with the revealed nodes are missing (the crucial changes are the second and third lines, i.e., `\usepackage[external]{forest}` and `tikzexternalize`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[external]{forest}
\tikzexternalize

\tikzset{% set up for transitions using tikz with beamer overlays
  invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}
\forestset{%
  declare toks={no node before}{1},
  declare toks={no edge before}{1},
  not before/.style={
    no node before=#1,
    for children={
      no edge before=#1,
    }
  },
  bottom up/.style={% based on Qrrbrbirlbel's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112895/
      /tikz/visible on=<\forestoption{no node before}->,
      /tikz/every label/.append style={visible on=<\forestoption{no node before}->},
      /tikz/every edge label/.append style={visible on=<\forestoption{no edge before}->},
      edge={/tikz/visible on=<\forestoption{no edge before}->},
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    /tikz/every label/.append style={text height=1ex, label distance=5pt},
    for tree={
      circle,
      draw,
      very thick,
      edge={very thick},
      s sep+=10pt,
      fill=white!25,
      minimum size=20pt,
      bottom up,
    }
    [, label=above:{car, bus, cat, dot}, not before=3
      [, label=above left:{car, bus}, not before=2
        [, label=below:car]
        [, label=below:bus]
      ]
      [, label=above right:{cat, dog}, not before=2
        [, label=below:cat]
        [, label=below:dog]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to have your cake and eat it too? Or are beamer overlays and `forest`/`tikz` externalization incompatible in a deep way that makes this impossible?

Editing to add: interestingly, the externalized pdf produced by the above *has three pages* with the relevant overlay transitions. But those transitions are not reflected in the main document.

Comment: related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183023/combining-beamer-tikz-externalize-and-standalone

Comment: @cfr I included a link to your answer in the post, and a description of what I changed in your code. Can you clarify what I can fix in my post?

Comment: @SimonC Sorry, I missed that and I found my local copy didn't have a note of the link. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @SimonC Are you interested in a workaround? Are you using pdfTeX?

Comment: Sure. Yes, I'm using pdfTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a workaround. It is driver-dependent - as written, it requires pdfTeX.

Note that, as written, this will almost certainly mess up externalised Ti*k*Z pictures which are not Forest trees. So the effect may need to be limited to local use, if that's a concern.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[external]{forest}
\tikzsetexternalprefix{ffigurau/}
\tikzset{%
  /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
    \pdfximage{#1.pdf}%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\the\pdflastximagepages}%
    {\includegraphics<\i>[page=\i]{#1}}%
  },
}
\tikzexternalize

\tikzset{% set up for transitions using tikz with beamer overlays
  invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}
\forestset{%
  declare toks={no node before}{1},
  declare toks={no edge before}{1},
  not before/.style={
    no node before=#1,
    for children={
      no edge before=#1,
    }
  },
  bottom up/.style={% based on Qrrbrbirlbel's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112895/
      /tikz/visible on=<\forestoption{no node before}->,
      /tikz/every label/.append style={visible on=<\forestoption{no node before}->},
      /tikz/every edge label/.append style={visible on=<\forestoption{no edge before}->},
      edge={/tikz/visible on=<\forestoption{no edge before}->},
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    /tikz/every label/.append style={text height=1ex, label distance=5pt},
    for tree={
      circle,
      draw,
      very thick,
      edge={very thick},
      s sep+=10pt,
      fill=white!25,
      minimum size=20pt,
      bottom up,
    }
    [, label=above:{car, bus, cat, dot}, not before=3
      [, label=above left:{car, bus}, not before=2
        [, label=below:car]
        [, label=below:bus]
      ]
      [, label=above right:{cat, dog}, not before=2
        [, label=below:cat]
        [, label=below:dog]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: use all externalised frames]

### Notes

The code redefines the command used to include the externalised image.

```
\tikzset{%
  /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
    \pdfximage{#1.pdf}%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\the\pdflastximagepages}%
    {\includegraphics<\i>[page=\i]{#1}}%
  },
}
```

This is not engine/driver-neutral because `\pdfximage` is not always defined. pdfTeX defines it, but other engines will not. (I can't check right now what does. Obviously TeX won't and XeTeX almost certainly not, while LuaTeX probably doesn't any more, even if it used to.)

`\pdfximage{#1.pdf}` sets the externalised file. `\the\pdflastximagepages` gives the total number of pages in the PDF. The loop then iterates over the pages, including each one on a distinct slide. For this, it uses the Beamer-modified syntax for `\includegraphics`, which supports an overlay specification.

So the externalisation itself doesn't get fixed: you don't get one externalised tree per slide. But the resulting frame ends up more-or-less correct because we include the PDF one page at a time using `\includegraphics`'s `page` key.

Comment: This does work for me! Would you be able to add some brief comments indicating what's different from the code in the original post, and why it works?

Comment: @SimonC Does this help?