# how to create dynamic graphics in latex beamer

Tags: beamer

How can I create a dynamic graphic in latex beamer?. for example, I want to display curves in the same graphic one by one, I mean one at a time. Thanks

Comment: Have a look to [Beamer: column alignment with tikzpicture inside](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80516/13304) especially the second part of my answer.