# Reveal TikZ Mindmap step by step with Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, mindmaps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step)

Using a mindmap example from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/mindmaps/), with only sligth modifications.
The target is to control what mindmap pieces are visible at a given time in the presentation.

Here is what i tried:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {Computer Science}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] (herb) {practical}  %herb
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] {algorithms} }
      child { node[concept] {data structures} }
      child { node[concept] {pro\-gramming languages} }
      child { node[concept] {software engineer\-ing} }
    }  
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] (muh) {applied}  %muh
      [clockwise from=-30]
      child { node[concept] {databases} }
      child { node[concept] {WWW} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {technical} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {theoretical} };
    \uncover<1-1>{herb} %should uncover on 1
    \uncover<2-2>{muh} %should uncover on 2
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Although i get to select the two different versions in the pdf, they appear identical. How can i display the mindmap step by step to help my audience follow my trail.

Comment: The same question was already asked in [tikzpicture in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55806/13304): have a look there and I suggest you to consider Daniel's approach.

Comment: The link that Claudio provided wouldn't have been obvious from a search- I have edited its title :) Let us know if your question is resolved...

Comment: I will try this tomorrow but this looks really close to what i am looking for.

Comment: Yes, the solution worked.