# Beamer and \foreach operator

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

This is my first figure trying to have it in the **beamer** with `\foreach`.

For some of you may be it is work five minutes ... but for me it has consumed the whole morning ...

**So my question:** How can I have separates `frame` for each image that produces from `\foreach` operator. The `\newframe` inside of `\foreach` does't work.

**My goal** was to make it has motion (reverse counterclockwise) ... but do not entangle two questions together

```
\documentclass{beamer}%{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{frame}{rotating - test}
%
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[thin,gray,step=0.25] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw[->] (-1.5,0)  -- (1.5,0) node[below]{$\phi_0$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.5)  -- (0,1.5) node[left]{$x$};
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\coordinate (C1) at (1,0);
\coordinate (C2) at (0.86,0.5);
\coordinate (C3) at (0.7,0.7);
\coordinate (C4) at (0.5,0.86);
\coordinate (C5) at (0,1);
\coordinate (C6) at (-0.5,0.86);
\coordinate (C7)at(-0.7,0.7);
\coordinate (C8)at(-0.86,0.5);
\coordinate (C9) at (-1,0);
\coordinate (C10) at (-0.86,-0.5);
\coordinate (C11)at(-0.7,-0.7);
\coordinate (C12) at (-0.5,-0.86);
\coordinate (C13) at (0,-1);
\coordinate (C14) at (0.5,-0.86);
\coordinate (C15) at (0.7,-0.7);
\coordinate (C16) at (0.86,-0.5);
% 
\foreach \Ctest in {(C1),(C2),(C3),(C4),(C5),(C6),
(C7),(C8),(C9),(C10),(C11),(C12),(C13),(C14),(C15),(C16)}{%
\draw [dashed] let \p1 = \Ctest
      in
    (\x1,\y1) -- (0,\y1)
    (\x1,\y1) -- (0,0);
\draw [red,thick,->] let \p1 = \Ctest
      in
    (0,0) -- (0,\y1) node[left] {$x$};
\draw [red,thick] let \p1 = \Ctest,
      \n1={atan2(\x1,\y1)}
      in
  (1,0) arc (0:\n1:1)
  (0,0)--(0.251,0) arc (0:\n1:0.25)--cycle;
\draw[fill=red] \Ctest circle [radius=0.06];
% \newframe %<<================================================
};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{center}
%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**1 Update:** After response of @Claudio Fiandrino and @Gonzalo Medina I have this figure. Τhe problem now is that I want the "orbit" of red body to have continuous increasing arc but the angle over 180 degrees do not defined
[image]

Comment: You can try to count your items in the foreach (like `\foreach \Ctest[count=\xi] in`) and then use the `\xi` within the famous style `visible on=<\xi>` from [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55806/13304). For example: `\draw [dashed,visible on=<\xi->]..`. Try to apply the style to all paths you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TikZ`and `beamer` are well integrated; in particular, TikZ commands are overlay-aware, so you can say, for example `\draw<+-> ...`; in this particular case, the `count=<macro>` syntax can be used (as **Caludio Fiandrino** suggested in his comment) to hold each position in the loop and then use `<macro>` for the overlay specification:

The original code can be highly simplified if instead of assigning coordinates for `\Ctest` one works with angles:

```
\documentclass{beamer}%{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{rotating - test}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[thin,gray,step=0.25] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw[->] (-1.5,0)  -- (1.5,0) node[below]{$\phi_0$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.5)  -- (0,1.5) node[left]{$x$};
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\foreach \Ctest[count=\i] in {0,30,45,60,90,120,135,150,180,210,225,240,270,300,315,330,360}{%
\draw<\i> [dashed] 
  (0,0) -- (\Ctest:1) -- (0,{sin(\Ctest)}) 
 node[left,red] {$x$};
\draw<\i> [red,thick] 
  (0,0)--(0.251,0) arc (0:\Ctest:0.25) --  cycle;
\draw<\i> [->,red,thick] 
  (0,0) -- (0,{sin(\Ctest)});
\draw<\i>[fill=red] ({cos(\Ctest)},{sin(\Ctest)}) circle [radius=0.06];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with the original code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}%{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\usecolortheme{whale}


\begin{document}
%
\begin{frame}{rotating - test}
%
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[thin,gray,step=0.25] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw[->] (-1.5,0)  -- (1.5,0) node[below]{$\phi_0$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.5)  -- (0,1.5) node[left]{$x$};
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\coordinate (C1) at (1,0);
\coordinate (C2) at (0.86,0.5);
\coordinate (C3) at (0.7,0.7);
\coordinate (C4) at (0.5,0.86);
\coordinate (C5) at (0,1);
\coordinate (C6) at (-0.5,0.86);
\coordinate (C7)at(-0.7,0.7);
\coordinate (C8)at(-0.86,0.5);
\coordinate (C9) at (-1,0);
\coordinate (C10) at (-0.86,-0.5);
\coordinate (C11)at(-0.7,-0.7);
\coordinate (C12) at (-0.5,-0.86);
\coordinate (C13) at (0,-1);
\coordinate (C14) at (0.5,-0.86);
\coordinate (C15) at (0.7,-0.7);
\coordinate (C16) at (0.86,-0.5);
% 
\foreach \Ctest[count=\i] in {(C1),(C2),(C3),(C4),(C5),(C6),
(C7),(C8),(C9),(C10),(C11),(C12),(C13),(C14),(C15),(C16)}{%
\draw<\i> [dashed] let \p1 = \Ctest
      in
    (\x1,\y1) -- (0,\y1)
    (\x1,\y1) -- (0,0);
\draw<\i> [red,thick,->] let \p1 = \Ctest
      in
    (0,0) -- (0,\y1) node[left] {$x$};
\ifnum\i<9\relax
{\draw<\i> [red,thick] let \p1 = \Ctest,
      \n1={atan2(\x1,\y1)}
      in
  (0,0)--(0.251,0) arc (0:\n1:0.25)--cycle;
}
\else
{
\draw<\i> [red,thick]
  (0.25,0mm) arc (0:180:0.25);
\draw<\i> [red,thick] let \p1 = \Ctest,
      \n1={atan2(-\x1,\y1)}
      in
  (0,0)--(-0.251,0) arc (0:-\n1:-0.25)--cycle;
}
\fi
\draw<\i>[fill=red] \Ctest circle [radius=0.06];
};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{center}
%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Αctually Is what I want to achieve by the morning. I just want the red circle to follow the movement but okay I have insert `<\i>` in `\draw<\i>[fill=red] \Ctest circle [radius=0.06];`.  Τhe problem now is that I want the "orbit" of red body to have continuous increasing arc but the angle over 180 degrees do not defined

Comment: If you want please insert `<\i>` in `\draw<\i>[fill=red] \Ctest circle [radius=0.06];` to display what Ι  would really want

Comment: @karathan I will do in some minutes; right now I have to leave for a lecture.

Comment: Oh! of course ... :-)

Comment: @karathan please see my updated answer; I used a conditional test to produce the desired effect; perhaps this could be done in a simpler way with some trigonometric trickery. Is something like that what you had in mind?

Comment: Indeed what I had in my mind. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @karathan You're welcome. I've updated my answer with a simplified version of the code (in particular, no conditional tests are needed now) that might be of interest.