# Using beamer overlays with forest generated trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-trees, trees, forest

I am using the `forest` package from Sašo Živanović in order to create a wide tree on a `beamer` slide.

Previously, I was using `qtree`. But due to the easier way of arranging nodes automatically with avoiding overlaps, I have switched to `forest`. However, with `qtree` I was able to manage overlays by a macro I have found in [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/tikzpicture-in-beamer/55827#55827)
with

```
\tikzset{
       invisible/.style={opacity=0},
       visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
       alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
         \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
      },
    }
```

This is sadly not working for the `forest` package. It does remove TikZ node attitudes (such as a drawn ellipse around a tree node) but the node text is visible in all slides as well as the subtrees and edges.

So is there a way to use `beamer` overlays with the `forest` package in order to partially make subtrees of a tree visible step by step with an animation?

**EDIT**

Ok here is a MWE for my different cases.

Note, that using TikZ is the result I would like to have with the `forest` package as well. In my code, the tree has a much bigger depth and playing along with sibling distance and left parameter isn't much fun, so I decided to use `forest` which auto formats the nodes.

```
\documentclass[english, ucs, xcolor={table, dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

% Different tree drawing packages
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{forest}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %Remove navigation bar


% Being able to set beamer visibility for child nodes in a tree graph
% Daniel's code:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/tikzpicture-in-beamer/55827#55827
% Use with child [color=.., visible on=<1->]
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}

\begin{document}

% tikz
\begin{frame}{tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}\scriptsize
        \tikzset{every node/.style={draw,ellipse}, sibling distance=40mm}

        \node {Picture root}
          child{node[fill=yellow]{First level class}
            child[visible on=<2->]{node[fill=gray]{subcategorized}}
            child[visible on=<2->]{node{another subcategory}
              child{node[fill=gray]{last node division}}
              child{node[fill=gray]{in two classes}}
            }
          }
          child {node[fill=gray]{Another long category}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}



% forest
\begin{frame}[plain]{Same with forest}
    \begin{forest} baseline, for tree={draw,ellipse,align=center}
        [Picture root
            [First level class,fill=yellow
                [subcategorized,fill=gray,visible on=<2->]
                [another subcategory,visible on=<2->
                    [last node division,fill=gray]
                    [in two classes,fill=gray] 
                ] 
            ]
            [Another long category,fill=gray]
        ]    
    \end{forest}
\end{frame}


% And qtree
\begin{frame}{And qtree}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=100mm, every node/.style={draw,ellipse}]
        \Tree [.\node{Picture root};
                [.\node{First level class};\onslide<2->
                    [.\node{subcategorized}; ]
                    [.\node{another subcategory}; 
                        [.\node{last node division}; ]
                        [.\node{in two classes}; ]
                    ]
                ]
                [.\onslide<1->\node{Another long category}; ]
            ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The following result is produced:

[image: TikZ standard, forest and qtree]

Comment: Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to play with?

Comment: The node text is still visible because it is not affected by `opacity=0`, it requires `text opacity=0` in the invisible style, too.

Comment: You could also check out the forest-animate style, available at https://github.com/sasozivanovic/forest-styles

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I defined a `/forest/visible on` option that passes its argument to

- `/tikz/visible on` to affect the actual node,
- and `/forest/edge` (this is the reason we need a `visible on` option in the `/forest` tree).

I asume you also want all following children (and their edges) to be invisible that's why we actually use `for tree` (meaning the subtree).

Other useful options are `for children`, `for descendants`, …; see section 3.3.6 Propagators of the `forest` manual for reference.

In this example we can use the `/forest` style `visible on` in a `for children` option of the parent node of `subcategorized` and `another subcategory`. (You may re-define/add various styles so that you can hide

- only the current node (and its edges),
- only the children of the current node (and their edges), and
- the current node and its children (and its and/or their edges).

### Code

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table, dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %Remove navigation bar
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}
\forestset{
  visible on/.style={
    for tree={
      /tikz/visible on={#1},
      edge+={/tikz/visible on={#1}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]{Same with forest}
    \begin{forest} baseline, for tree={draw,ellipse,align=center}
        [Picture root
            [First level class,fill=yellow,for children={visible on=<2->}
                [subcategorized,fill=gray]
                [another subcategory
                    [last node division,fill=gray]
                    [in two classes,fill=gray] 
                ] 
            ]
            [Another long category,fill=gray]
        ]    
    \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Wow, that does the trick exactly the way I want it to behave. Thank you for the answer and the good explanation.