# tikz: pause between generations in a tree in beamer presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-trees

I have been writing the following code for a tikz-tree:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture} [nodes={draw, rectangle, fill=orange!30, sibling distance=10cm,minimum height=2em}, ->]

\node[fill=orange!30, rectangle]{0}
child { node {A} }
child [missing]
    child { node[fill=orange!30, rectangle] {F: 3} 
    child { node[fill=orange!30, rectangle] {G: 28} 
    {child {node{Z}}}
      child {node[fill=orange!30, rectangle] {L: 22}}
        child [missing]
      child {node {B: 296}}
    }}
child [missing]
child { node {C: 167} }
child [missing]
child { node {D: 92}};
\end{tikzpicture}

 \end{figure}
 \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

I would like to have pause between generations: would you help me in doing so?

Thanks a lot :)

1dre

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313720/how-can-i-use-pause-for-each-level-in-beamer-presentation-to-appear-sequentiall, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109950/using-beamer-overlays-with-forest-generated-trees or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117309/step-by-step-revealing-of-tikz-tree-using-opacity-trick-and-overlays-in-beamer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the TikZ code...

Paste them under the original one... place... `\action` between them... and leave the last copy untouched... but in each copy inserted before... either start changing color to be invisible or if possible delete the codes corresponding to the generations...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}[label=CCS]
\frametitle{Motivations and Directions}
\framesubtitle{The Cache County Study (CCS)}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture} [nodes={draw, rectangle, fill=orange!30, sibling distance=10cm,minimum height=2em}, ->]

\action<1>{\node[fill=orange!30, rectangle]{0};}

\action<2>{\node[fill=orange!30, rectangle]{0}
child { node {A} }
child [missing]
    child { node[fill=orange!30, rectangle] {F: 3} 
    }
child [missing]
child { node {C: 167} }
child [missing]
child { node {D: 92}};
}

\action<3>{\node[fill=orange!30, rectangle]{0}
child { node {A} }
child [missing]
    child { node[fill=orange!30, rectangle] {F: 3} 
    child { node[fill=orange!30, rectangle] {G: 28} 
    }}
child [missing]
child { node {C: 167} }
child [missing]
child { node {D: 92}};
}

\action<4>{\node[fill=orange!30, rectangle]{0}
child { node {A} }
child [missing]
    child { node[fill=orange!30, rectangle] {F: 3} 
    child { node[fill=orange!30, rectangle] {G: 28} 
    {child {node{Z}}}
    }}
child [missing]
child { node {C: 167} }
child [missing]
child { node {D: 92}};
}

\action<5>{\node[fill=orange!30, rectangle]{0}
child { node {A} }
child [missing]
    child { node[fill=orange!30, rectangle] {F: 3} 
    child { node[fill=orange!30, rectangle] {G: 28} 
    {child {node{Z}}}
      child {node[fill=orange!30, rectangle] {L: 22}}
        child [missing]
      child {node {B: 296}}
    }}
child [missing]
child { node {C: 167} }
child [missing]
child { node {D: 92}};
}



\end{tikzpicture}



\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: incremental display of tree by level]

Comment: Does `\pause` really work in this situation? For me, it just generates errors.

Comment: \pause was an errror... \action was the answer...

Comment: @samcarter ^^ You have mail, I think ;).

Comment: Welcome to this quiet galactic backwater!

Comment: @cfr is it good? ☺

Comment: As quiet galactic backwaters go, it is pretty good - almost silent and definitely part of some galaxy or other, but a bit on the dry side. On the other hand, perhaps the lack of wateriness has its upside given that the place exists in intergalactic cyberspace.