# How to draw straight line cross different level and make it easy to use \only<n>{...}?

Tags: tikz-qtree

I'm a new/beginner on tikz-qtree package, and trying to draw the straight line from F under R to T (level 2). Another problem, it not easy to use command \only{...}, how to use \only{...} in the better way.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=0.5cm]
\tikzset{grow'=up,frontier/.style={distance from root=150pt}}
\only<1>{
\Tree [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; 
[.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; [.$T$    
\edge[draw=none]; $(P$ ] \edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none];  
$\wedge$ ] \edge[draw=none]; [.$T$ \edge[draw=none]; $Q)$ ] ]  
\edge[draw=none]; $\vee$ \edge[draw=none]; [ \edge[draw=none]; [.$F$  
\edge[draw=none]; $R$ ] ] ]
\edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; $\leftrightarrow$ ] 
\edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ }  
\edge[draw=none]; [.$\sim F$ \edge[draw=none]; $(\sim R$ ] ] 
\edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } 
\edge[draw=none]; $\wedge$ ] ] \edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } 
\edge[draw=none]; [.$\sim T$ \edge[draw=none]; $\sim Q)$ ] ] ]
]
}
\only<2>{
\Tree [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; 
[.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; [.$T$ [.$T$ \edge[draw=none]; $(P$ ]   
\edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; $\wedge$ ] [.$T$ 
\edge[draw=none]; $Q)$ ] ] \edge[draw=none]; $\vee$ \edge[draw=none]; [ 
\edge[draw=none]; [.$F$ \edge[draw=none]; $R$ ] ] ]
\edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; $\leftrightarrow$ ] 
\edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; [.$T$ [.$\sim F$   
\edge[draw=none]; $(\sim R$ ] ] \edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } 
\edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; $\wedge$ ] ] 
\edge[draw=none]; [.$F$ [.$\sim T$ \edge[draw=none]; $\sim Q)$ ] ] ]
]
}
\only<3>{
\Tree [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; 
[.$T$ [.$T$ [.$T$ \edge[draw=none]; $(P$ ] \edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ }
\edge[draw=none]; $\wedge$ ] [.$T$ \edge[draw=none]; $Q)$ ] ]  
\edge[draw=none]; $\vee$  [ [.$F$ \edge[draw=none]; $R$ ] ] ]
\edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; $\leftrightarrow$ ] 
\edge[draw=none]; [.$F$ [.$T$ [.$\sim F$ \edge[draw=none]; $(\sim R$ ] ]    
\edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } 
\edge[draw=none]; $\wedge$ ] ] [.$F$ [.$\sim T$ \edge[draw=none]; $\sim Q)$ ] ] ]
]
}
\only<4>{
\Tree [.\alert{$F$}
[.$T$ [.$T$ [.$T$ \edge[draw=none]; $(P$ ] \edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ }  
\edge[draw=none]; $\wedge$ ] [.$T$ \edge[draw=none]; $Q)$ ] ]  
\edge[draw=none]; $\vee$  [ [.$F$ \edge[draw=none]; $R$ ] ] ]
\edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; $\leftrightarrow$ ] 
[.$F$ [.$T$ [.$\sim F$ \edge[draw=none]; $(\sim R$ ] ] 
\edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } \edge[draw=none]; [.\mbox{ } 
\edge[draw=none]; $\wedge$ ] ] [.$F$ [.$\sim T$ \edge[draw=none]; $\sim Q)$ ] ] ]
]
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Forest is an option, you can automate the incremental uncovering, improve alignment and simplify the code required to specify the tree.

Forest is a specialist Ti*k*Z-based package for drawing trees. Some of the code below has a distinguished pedigree and the code is annotated accordingly to attribute (I hope) all those involved. (If I've omitted somebody, please let me know!)

I define a special Forest style `semantic tree` for drawing trees of the kind in the question.

- All nodes are typeset in maths mode, but those above the last level (i.e. below the sentence) are wrapped by `\text{}` so that the `T`/`F` are upright. Hence, `$...$` must be used here for negations.
- The tree is automatically rendered visible incrementally, with one line per slide, as shown in the question. Since this doesn't require anything additional in the tree specification at all, I assume this is a simple enough method ;).

In addition,

- I use `\tnot` for the tilde representation of `not`, which corrects the spacing. (TeX assumes that the symbol represents a binary relation, which is incorrect.)
- `\ob` and `\cb` typeset opening and closing brackets without affecting the alignment of the following or preceding content.
- `connective=<connective>` adds a node containing a connective to the right of the current one.
- `direct connect to=<node>` draws a direct connection between the current node and the specified node, rather than following the usual path.

The document preamble is quite extensive but the pay-off is that the tree itself can be specified very simply and concisely.

```
\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    semantic tree
    [F
      [T
        [T
          [T
            [\ob P, connective=\land]
          ]
          [T
            [Q\cb, connective=\lor]
          ]
        ]
        [
          [F, direct connect to=!uu
            [R, connective=\leftrightarrow]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [F
        [T
          [$\tnot$F
            [\ob\tnot R, connective=\land]
          ]
        ]
        [F
          [$\tnot$T
            [\tnot Q\cb]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{frame}
```

The result is 5 slides.

[image: forest solution]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{% set up for transitions using tikz with beamer overlays - developed by Daniel (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/) and, in ear lier form, by Matthew Leingang (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155/) and modified for this use, I think by Qrrbrbirlbel (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112471/)
  invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
  transparent/.style={opacity=0.1,text opacity=0.1},
  opaque on/.style={alt=#1{}{transparent}},
  alerted/.style={color=alerttextdefaultfg},
  alert on/.style={alt=#1{alerted}{}},
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\tnot}{\ensuremath{\mathord{\sim}}}
\newcommand*\ob{\llap{(}}
\newcommand*\cb{\rlap{)}}
\forestset{%
  semantic tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      math content,
      tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier ##1}{level()},
      parent anchor=children,
      child anchor=parent,
      grow'=90,
    },
    delay={%
      where level=0{%
        red,
      }{},
      where content={}{%
        coordinate,
      }{},
      where n children=0{%
        calign with current,
      }{%
        content/.wrap value=\text{##1},
      },
    },
    before packing={%
      where n children=0{%
        tier=terminus,
        no edge,
      }{},
    },
    before computing xy={%
      where n children=0{%
        l'-=10pt,
      }{},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        for current and ancestors/.wrap pgfmath arg={%
          visible from=##1,
        }{int(5-(level()))},
      },
    },
  },
  connective/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      insert after={[#1, math content]},
    },
  },
  direct connect to/.style={%
    edge path'=(#1.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor),
    tempcounta/.pgfmath=id("#1"),
    for nodewalk={%
      fake=parent,
      while={id()!=(tempcounta)}{current,fake=parent},
    }{%
      no edge,
    },
  },
  visible on/.style={% developed by Qrrbrbirlbel (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112471/)
    for tree={%
      /tikz/visible on={#1},
      edge={/tikz/visible on={#1}}}},
  opaque on/.style={%
    for tree={%
      /tikz/opaque on={#1},
      edge={/tikz/opaque on={#1}}}},
  alerted on/.style={%
    for tree={%
      /tikz/alerted on={#1},
      edge={/tikz/alerted on={#1}}}},
  visible from/.style={% based on Qrrbrbirlbel's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112895/
    /tikz/visible on=<#1->,
    /tikz/every label/.append style={visible on=<#1->},
    for children={%
      /tikz/every edge label/.append style={visible on=<#1->},
      edge={/tikz/visible on=<#1->},
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    semantic tree
    [F
      [T
        [T
          [T
            [\ob P, connective=\land]
          ]
          [T
            [Q\cb, connective=\lor]
          ]
        ]
        [
          [F, direct connect to=!uu
            [R, connective=\leftrightarrow]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [F
        [T
          [$\tnot$F
            [\ob\tnot R, connective=\land]
          ]
        ]
        [F
          [$\tnot$T
            [\tnot Q\cb]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm a fan of Forest, I think it is fair to say ;). It is very, very nice!