# Hide parts of forest-generated trees in Beamer overlays

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, forest

I am trying to use a tree built by the forest package in a beamer animation. To uncover part of the tree (I want it to be revealed from bottom to top) I use the method described in [Using beamer overlays with forest generated trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109950/using-beamer-overlays-with-forest-generated-trees) while modifying it slightly such that it only hides the current node and not the whole subtree.

The problem now is that I can manually hide the nodes by simply adding the `visible on=<#>` option, but for some reason this does not work when adding the option through a where statement.

The second part of the question was an oddity I discovered while trying to clean up my code - when combining the two `forestset` options, it no longer hides the edges as well as the nodes, but only the nodes. (Now even when adding the visibility statement manually.

The code I am trying this with is the following: (in the tree I added one position

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage[linguistics,external]{forest}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{highlight/.style={darkred,very thick},}
\tikzset{positive/.style={fill=examplegreen}}
\tikzset{negative/.style={fill=examplered}}
\colorlet{parameterblue}{rgb:cyan,2;white,4;blue,3}
\colorlet{examplegreen}{rgb:green,4;white,4;black,1}
\colorlet{examplered}{rgb:orange,2;red,3;white,4}
\colorlet{darkred}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!80!black}
\newcommand{\plus}{\color{darkgreen}{$+$}}
\newcommand{\minus}{\color{darkred}{$-$}}
\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
  beschr/.style={remember picture,overlay,font=\small},
  highlight on/.style={{alt=#1{highlight}{}}},
}
\forestset{
  highlight on/.style={/tikz/highlight on={#1},}
  }
\forestset{
  visible on/.style={
    % for tree={
    /tikz/visible on={#1},
    for children={
      edge={/tikz/visible on={#1}}}
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

   \begin{forest}
   %aligns the bottom lines
    where n children=0{tier=terminal,!u.tier=second,!uu.tier=third}{math content},
    where n children=0{!u.visible on=<2->,!uu.visible on=<3->,!uuu.visible on=<4->}{},
    for tree={l sep+=1em,}
   [ {\{m_7,m_{11}\}}
     [{\{m_8,m_9\}}
       [{\{m_1,m_2,m_4\}}
         [{\{m_1,m_3\}}
            [1][2],
         ]
         [{\{\dots\}}
           [3][4\\\plus]
         ]
       ]
       [{\{m_7\}}
         [ {\{m_7\}}
           [{5\onslide<5->{\\\minus}},for ancestors={edge={highlight on=<5->}},edge={highlight on=<5->}][6]
         ]
         [ {\{\dots\}}
           [7\\\plus][8\\\plus]
         ]
       ]
     ]
    [{\{\dots\}},visible on=<2->
     [{\{\dots\}}[9\\\minus][10]]
     [{\{\dots\}}[11][12\\\minus]]
    ]
   ]
   \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

for the second part of the question, I exchanged the block containing the two forestset statements

```
\forestset{
  highlight on/.style={/tikz/highlight on={#1},}
  }
\forestset{
  visible on/.style={
    % for tree={
    /tikz/visible on={#1},
    for children={
      edge={/tikz/visible on={#1}}}
    }
}
```

by a single forestset statement

```
\forestset{
  highlight on/.style={/tikz/highlight on={#1},}
  visible on/.style={
    % for tree={
    /tikz/visible on={#1},
    for children={
      edge={/tikz/visible on={#1}}}
    }
}
```

and then it did not hide any of the edges. Any suggestions about what I am missing here?

Comment: You're missing a comma at the end of the `highlight on` line in the combo settings. `highlight on/.style={/tikz/highlight on={#1},}` -> `highlight on/.style={/tikz/highlight on={#1},},`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, possibly. This is a modified version of some customisations I use, so credits for code are included as comments.

[image: show me up]

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  highlight/.style={darkred,very thick},
  positive/.style={fill=examplegreen},
  negative/.style={fill=examplered},
}
\colorlet{parameterblue}{rgb:cyan,2;white,4;blue,3}
\colorlet{examplegreen}{rgb:green,4;white,4;black,1}
\colorlet{examplered}{rgb:orange,2;red,3;white,4}
\colorlet{darkred}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!80!black}
\newcommand{\plus}{\color{darkgreen}{$+$}}
\newcommand{\minus}{\color{darkred}{$-$}}
\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
  highlight on/.style={{alt=#1{highlight}{}}},
}
\forestset{
  visible on/.style={% developed by Qrrbrbirlbel (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112471/)
    for tree={%
      /tikz/visible on={#1},
      edge={/tikz/visible on={#1}}}},
  highlight on/.style={%
    /tikz/highlight on={#1},
    edge={/tikz/highlight on={#1}}},
  highlight edge on/.style={%
    edge={/tikz/highlight on={#1}}},
  declare toks={no node before}{1},
  declare toks={no edge before}{1},
  declare count={gweladwy}{1},
  declare count={sleidiau}{1},
  not before/.style={%
    no node before=#1,
    for children={%
      no edge before=#1}},
  bottom up/.style={% based on Qrrbrbirlbel's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112895/
    /tikz/visible on=<\forestoption{no node before}->,
    /tikz/every label/.append style={visible on=<\forestoption{no node before}->},
    /tikz/every edge label/.append style={visible on=<\forestoption{no edge before}->},
    edge={/tikz/visible on=<\forestoption{no edge before}->}},
  show me up/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      tempcounta/.max={>O{level}}{tree},
      where n children=0{
        tier=terminus, 
        no edge before=2,
      }{
        tempcountb/.process={ORw2+n{level}{tempcounta}{(##2-##1)+1}}, 
        tempcountc/.process={Rw+n{tempcountb}{##1+1}}, 
        tier/.register=tempcountb, 
        math content, 
        no node before/.register=tempcountb, 
        no edge before/.register=tempcountc,
      },
    },
    for tree={bottom up},
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={l sep+=1em},
    show me up
   [ {\{m_7,m_{11}\}}
     [{\{m_8,m_9\}}
       [{\{m_1,m_2,m_4\}}
         [{\{m_1,m_3\}}
            [1][2],
         ]
         [{\{\dots\}}
           [3][4\\\plus]
         ]
       ]
       [{\{m_7\}}
         [ {\{m_7\}}
           [{5\onslide<5->{\\\minus}}, for current and ancestors={highlight edge on=<5->}][6]
         ]
         [ {\{\dots\}}
           [7\\\plus][8\\\plus]
         ]
       ]
     ]
    [{\{\dots\}}%,visible on=<2->
     [{\{\dots\}}[9\\\minus][10]]
     [{\{\dots\}}[11][12\\\minus]]
    ]
   ]
   \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```