# shaped node in tree

Tags: diagrams, trees

I want to create this tree that each node have its own shape. for example each nodes be circle and leaves be square.
[image]

this code perfectly work but I want to use tree in my code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix [column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm] {
        & & \node (in) [draw, shape=circle] {Income}; \\
        \node (lo) [draw, shape=rectangle, minimum size=1cm]    {Loan}; & &
        \node (ms) [draw, shape=circle] {MS}; & & &
        \node (cr) [draw, shape=circle] {CR}; \\
        & \node (lo2) [draw, shape=rectangle, minimum size=1cm] {Loan}; & &
        \node (noLoan) [draw, shape=rectangle, minimum size=1cm] {No loan}; &
        \node (lo3) [draw, shape=rectangle, minimum size=1cm] {Loan}; & &
        \node (noLoan2) [draw, shape=rectangle, minimum size=1cm] {No loan};\\
    };
    \draw[->] (in) -- (lo);
    \draw[->] (in) -- (ms);
    \draw[->] (in) -- (cr);
    \draw[->] (ms) -- (lo2);
    \draw[->] (ms) -- (noLoan);
    \draw[->] (cr) -- (lo3);
    \draw[->] (cr) -- (noLoan2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE¨! What you try?

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. couldn't write code here so I edit the question.

Comment: That is right that you edit your question. Now all can see your effort and will see, where you stuck. I will try to help you latter afternoon ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drawing as tree by use of the `forest` package. A wee bit sophisticated but short code:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest} % it load tikz too
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree =  {
% nodes styles
        draw, 
        minimum size=3em,
        inner sep=2pt,
  where level = 2{}{circle, draw},
        align = center,
       anchor = north,
       %child anchor=north,
% tree style
         edge = {-Straight Barb, semithick},
        s sep = 12 mm,
        l sep = 16 mm,
  where level = 1{s sep=2mm}{},
% edge labels
EL/.style 2 args = {edge label={%
                    node[midway, font=\footnotesize, align=center,
                         inner sep=2pt, anchor=south #1]{#2}},
                    },
            }    
[Income, 
    [loan, rectangle, EL={east}{high}]
    [MS, EL={east}{medium}, 
         before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}
        [loan, EL={east}{maried}] 
        [no\\ loan, EL={west}{no\\ married}]   
    ]
    [CR, EL={west}{low},
        [loan, EL={east}{good}] 
        [no\\ loan, EL={west}{poor}]   
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was great but is there any way to use tree easier?

Comment: @ErfanRiahi, what you mean with "easier"? Code is simple, concise and relative easy to understand (regardless that I said that it is sophisticated ;-), this I mean in comparison to your codein question.

Comment: You don't need `where` inside `for tree` - you just add additional processing. It's more efficient to use `if` or to take the `where` outside the `for tree`. The same goes for the style definition. You don't need to define for each node individually ;).

Comment: See https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64801439#64801439. @ErfanRiahi You asked for a `tree`. `forest` provides one fairly straightforward way to create a tree. If this isn't what you wanted, can you clarify what you do want?

Comment: @cfr No, it's ok. thanks.
another question: how can I use this tree in beamer? and is it possible to use pause for each node?

Comment: @ErfanRiahi To use it in Beamer, you just load `forest` and put the tree inside a `frame`. I doubt you can use `\pause`, but you can specify the slides on which each node of the tree appears using Ti*k*Z styles. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112471/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112895/. I also have some posts specific to forest e.g.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417110/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392608/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393437/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417110/.

Comment: @ErfanRiahi, if you have new problems, please ask new question that other people perhaps can help you.  My answer (perfectly) solve your question: show how to draw your image as tree. Regarding to your recent comments, it becoming unclear, what is your problem.

Comment: @Zarko Yes your answer was really helpful and I'm thankful about that but after that I had a new problem. if I couldn't solve it, I'll ask a new question with more clear deatail.

Comment: @ErfanRiahi, good to hear this. So, now you may consider to accept answer (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer) and by this inform audience here, that your question, as it is, is solved.