# How do I decouple child nodes in tikz trees into separate node elements?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-node

Assume I have a tree of the following form:

```
\node (r) {Root}
  child { node (c1) {Left Child} }
  child { node (c2) {Right Child} }
  ;
```

Now, I want to put this into a beamer frame and apply `\only` and `\uncover` to individual `\node;` elements. But if I have one huge tree, I cannot do that. So is there a way to decouple the child nodes, and refer to the parent node by name?

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? And could you also include a sketch of what the result should look like?

Comment: @samcarter How would that help in this case?

Comment: It would give the people willing to help you something to start with when they work on a solution for you.

Comment: Because then one could give a better answer. Just load the `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}` library and try `\node (r) {Root}
  child { node[visible on=<2->] (c1) {Left Child} }
  child { node[visible on=<3->] (c2) {Right Child} }
  ;` No guarantee that it works because there is no MWE to play with, as already explained by @samcarter.  (@samcarter I need to take off and have no interest in answering this question, but will be happy to use my remaining upvote for today for your answer. ;-)

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.

Comment: @marmot Thanks for the offer! In the mean time the OP found an answer him/herself.

Comment: @marmot The question was about how to decouple nodes. The `\uncover` was a motivation why I need to uncover them. Your `visible on` trick doesn't work, because it doesn't hide the arrows between the nodes, only the node itself.

Comment: @bitmask Maybe you could answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436389/overlay-of-edges-of-a-tree-created-with-one-command ?

Comment: Oh yes, it seems that asks for something very similar. I'll give it a go.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447240/1498

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple, one can leave empty childs and then reference them in a separate node:

```
\node (r) {Root}
  child 
  child 
  ;
\node (c1) at (r-1) {Left Child};
\node (c2) at (r-2) {Right Child};
```

The syntax is basically appending `-1`, `-2`, etc to the parent node's identifier.

Child nodes can also be named:

```
\node (r) {Root}
  child {coordinate (left)}
  child {coordinate {right)}
  ;
\node (c1) at (left) {Left Child};
\node (c2) at (right) {Right Child};
```