# highlight a node in tikz

Tags: tikz-trees, highlighting

```
\begin{frame} {Family work up }
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}]
    \node {Patient}[edge from parent fork down]
        child { node {Daughter 32 years}}
        child { node {Son 28 years}}
        child { node {\color{red} {Daughter 23 years}}}         
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Hi 
Above code produces a small family tree. I would like to highlight a child (Daughter 23 years) suggesting she also has got a disease. This can be done by encircling it with a box or highlighting it with a color. Kindly help.

Comment: Your answer below would be better as an edit to your question. Also, please post a full working example: example code that does not compile isn't very helpful because anyone who is inclined to help has to first figure out what packages etc you are using...people are much more likely to help if you give them a working example to start with.

Comment: Do you want it highlighted on the same frame or on two different overlays?

Comment: Thanks. it would be better if on two different overlays with animation if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You like to have something like this?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[compress,final]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Family work up }
\begin{tikzpicture}[
level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}]
    \node {Patient}[edge from parent fork down]
        child { node {Daughter 32 years}}
        child { node {Son 28 years}}
        child { node[draw=red] {Daughter 23 years}}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

or

\begin{tikzpicture}[
level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}]
    \node {Patient}[edge from parent fork down]
        child { node {Daughter 32 years}}
        child { node {Son 28 years}}
        child { node[fill=gray!30] {Daughter 23 years}}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Nodes in tree you can design as other nodes in `tikzpicture`, just add to them desired parameters, similarly as I do above. And by the way: sibling distance 5cm is to big that with it the tree can be fitted onto slide so I reduce it to 3cm.

Answer (score 1):

Also, using the macro from [Using beamer overlays with forest generated trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109950/using-beamer-overlays-with-forest-generated-trees), to have two overlays:

```
\documentclass[compress,final]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
        \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}

\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Family work up }
\begin{tikzpicture}[
level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}]
    \node {Patient}[edge from parent fork down]
        child { node {Daughter 32 years}}
        child { node {Son 28 years}}
        child { node[alt={<2->{fill=yellow}{}}] {Daughter 23 years}}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

With the result:

[image: result]