# beamer animation in tikz cannot specify separate steps

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am using a piece of code (`\tikzset`) which people have repeatedly been posting in various questions, e.g. [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step/55827#55827) and [highlight a node in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290523/highlight-a-node-in-tikz).

But now, I want to specify a piece of animation that highlights in step 1 and 3, separately (`alt=<1,3>`). However, this code gives pgf error. How should this problem be resolved?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} 
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle, draw, alt=<1,3>{red}{black}]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen this question? It deals specifically with the case `alt=<1,3>`. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84513/highlighting-in-beamer-using-tikz-nodes

Comment: @PatrickT sorry I don't understand that answer. it didn't change the definition of `alt`. in my example, I directly use `alt=` which is not quite the same as that answer which uses `BeamerAlert`

Answer (score 1):

To prevent tikz from thinking the `,` would be the end of the key value, place your list of overlays in `{1,3}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle, draw, alt=<{1,3}>{red}{black}]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```