# Uncover nodes and edges in reverse

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Considering the following Tikz example, how can one uncover nodes from bottom to top? I would like the node **C** appear on slide 1, then **B** on slide 2 along with the path from `B to C` and finally node **A** along with the path from `A to B`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    level 1/.style={every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={->,solid,draw=blue}} },
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=12mm,every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={->,solid,draw=blue}}},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=8mm,every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={->,solid,draw=blue}}},
    semithick]

    \node[draw=none] (root) {A}
    child[] {node[draw=none] {B}
      child[] {node[draw=none] {C}
      }};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [Using beamer overlays with forest generated trees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109950/using-beamer-overlays-with-forest-generated-trees).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combination of `\onslide` for text and `draw on` from [aobs-tikz](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) for the arrows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{trees,overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        level 1/.style={every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={->,solid,draw=blue,draw on=<{3-}>}} },
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=12mm,every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={->,solid,draw=blue,draw on=<{2-}>}}},
        level 3/.style={sibling distance=8mm,every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={->,solid,draw=blue}}},
        semithick]

        \node[draw=none] (root) {{\onslide<3->{A}}}
        child[] {node[draw=none] {{\onslide<2->{B}}}
            child[] {node[draw=none] {C}
            }};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

You may wanto to use something different instead of `onslide` if you need to reserve space and stuff like that.

[image]