# How should I make blur shadows appear with their nodes in a Forest tree in Beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, forest, shadows

A little while ago, I asked [How can I make drop shadows appear with their nodes in a Forest tree in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357364/how-can-i-make-drop-shadows-appear-with-their-nodes-in-a-forest-tree-in-beamer) At the time, I just eliminated the shadows and went with a shodowless tree. Later, however, I found a very awkward method which worked. A while after that, I received [Symbol 1 provided a real answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357412/).

Now I am trying to adapt that solution for my real uses. First, I wanted to make the code conditional on the loading of the appropriate library, so that I can include it in my standard Beamer configuration files.

```
\makeatletter
\pgfkeysifdefined{/tikz/shadow scale}{%
  % ateb Symbol 1: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357412/
  \def\tikzopacityregister{1}%
  \tikzset{
    opacity/.append code={
      \pgfmathsetmacro\tikzopacityregister{#1*\tikzopacityregister}%
    },
    opacity aux/.code={% this is the original definition of opacity
      \tikz@addoption{\pgfsetstrokeopacity{#1}\pgfsetfillopacity{#1}}
    },
    every shadow/.style={opacity aux=\tikzopacityregister}
  }%
}{}
\makeatother
```

I couldn't find something like `\if@tikzlibrary@loaded`, so I went with testing for the existence of a PGF key. If there's a way of testing whether a library is loaded, that would obviously be preferable.

Second, I want to make the code work with `shadows.blur`, so I can use `blur shadow` as well as `drop shadow`. The following seems to work, but I'm not sure if it is even vaguely reasonable as a method.

```
opacity/.append code={
  \pgfmathsetmacro\tikzopacityregister{#1*\tikzopacityregister}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfbs@opacity{\tikzopacityregister}% cfr: added for blur shadows
},
```

I tried to append something to, say `shadow opacity` or to set this when `opacity` is set. However, I couldn't get this to work and ended up with the above. Again, not great as it relies on an internal implementation detail rather than just the public interface.

I also still get thin outlines of the shadows in this case, but that may be a viewer artefact. (They are still there at 1600% magnification, however, which is the most Okular provides.)

What is the correct way to do this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{% set up for transitions using tikz with beamer overlays - developed by Daniel (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/) and, in earlier form, by Matthew Leingang (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155/) and modified for this use, I think by Qrrbrbirlbel (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112471/)
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}
\forestset{%
  visible with edge from/.style={% based on visible on, developed by Qrrbrbirlbel (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112471/)
    /tikz/visible on=<#1->,
    /tikz/every label/.append style={visible on=<#1->},
    edge={/tikz/visible on=<#1->},
  },
}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeysifdefined{/tikz/shadow scale}{%
  % ateb Symbol 1: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357412/
  \def\tikzopacityregister{1}%
  \tikzset{
    opacity/.append code={
      \pgfmathsetmacro\tikzopacityregister{#1*\tikzopacityregister}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfbs@opacity{\tikzopacityregister}% cfr: added for blur shadows
    },
    opacity aux/.code={% this is the original definition of opacity
      \tikz@addoption{\pgfsetstrokeopacity{#1}\pgfsetfillopacity{#1}}
    },
    every shadow/.style={opacity aux=\tikzopacityregister}
  }%
}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      draw,
      fill=white,
      blur shadow,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        tempcounta/.option=level,
        tempcounta'+=1,
        visible with edge from/.register=tempcounta,
      }
    }
    [first slide
      [second slide[third slide][third slide]]
      [second slide]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: not-quite ideal output, but close]

Comment: If I recall correctly, blur is eventually overlapping lines with various width. In case there is opacity≠1, you have to make a transparency group for those lines.

Comment: @Symbol1 Hmmm. Thanks. I think I'll live with the lines then as I have no idea how to apply a transparency group here.

Comment: Or maybe I should stick to sharp shadows here.

Comment: As for checking library, you probably want to see `tikz.code.tex` line 5317 and 18.

Comment: It looks fine on Preview, Chrome, Adobe Reader, TeXLive, and ImageMagick. Maybe... viewer-dependent again?

Comment: @Symbol1 Sounds like it. Thanks. If it looks OK in Adobe, that will do as I'll  use Adobe to display the slide on a networked machine. Viewers are a pain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as issue of the pdf viewer