# Building a `forest` tree :-) step by step

Tags: beamer, forest

I would like to get the following steps using `beamer`. I would need some hints to start my coding...

[image]

Here is the code of the tree.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{forest}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
  for tree = {math content},
  where n children = 0 {tier = word} {}
  [243
    [3   [3^1]]
    [81
      [9   [3^2]]       
      [9   [3^2]]
    ]
  ]
  \path (!11.base east)  -- (!211.base west) node[midway, anchor=base]{$\times$};
  \path (!211.base east) -- (!221.base west) node[midway, anchor=base]{$\times$};
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Depth first step by step construction on forest tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489718/)

Comment: Have a look at the `overlay-beamer-styles` tikz library

Comment: Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112471/36296

Comment: Thanks for the links.