# Use multiple tikz picture with onslide command in the single frame in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have multiple tikz pictures in the single frame in beamer. In the first tikz picture I was able to use the only overlay and onslide command. However, for the second picture I am not able to achive the same effect. What I want is at onslide<4> onwards I want to show the contents on the second tikz picture.

The sample code inside a frame is as follows:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Age of Water under dye from all Rivers}

    \only<1->{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
        \node [](0,0)(start){ \includegraphics[clip,trim=10 370 400 10,width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.85\textheight]{figures/dye-rivers}};
%       \draw [step=0.5cm,thin,dotted] (-5,-4) grid(5,4);
%       \node [circle]at (-4.5,0){0};
%       \node [circle,radius=0.9cm,fill=red!30,] at (-4.5,0)(a){};
        \onslide<2->{\draw [red,fill=red!30](-4.3,-0.2)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-3.3,0)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-2.5,-0.7)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-4.,-0.8)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-4.,-1.2)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](4.3,1.6)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](3.3,2.7)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](1.6,3.5)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](1.3,3.5)circle(0.1cm);}         
        \node [rectangle,text width=4cm,red] at (5.5,3) (return) {$Q_2 = 169 A^{0.616}$     \linebreak Mason et. al. 1998};
        \onslide<3-> \node [rectangle,text width=4cm,red] at (5,0) (return) {Smaller near the source     \linebreak Increases away from the source};
        \onslide<3-> \draw [red](-3.3,-1.5) circle(0.7cm);%wolf bay small age
    \end{tikzpicture}}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [](0,0)(start){ \includegraphics[clip,trim=400 370 0 0,width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.85\textheight]{figures/dye-rivers}};
    \draw [step=0.5,dotted](-5,-4) grid (5,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{frame}
```

Comment: Instead of using Beamer's overlay commands, consider using TikZ keys to control overlay effects within a `tikzpicture` environment.  See for example this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/18228

Comment: That works on only one tikz picture. I couldn't make it work for multiple tikz picture. Currently I have two tikz pictures in one frame.

Comment: You have several elements besides the images; what exactly should appear on each slide; in particular, on slide 4?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina From slide 4 onwards, I want to show the elements of the second tikzpicture only.

Comment: @Jdbaba Please see my answer. Is it something like that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jdbaba: That method also works for multiple `tikzpicture` environments. In your case, you only need to pass the option `[visible on=<4->]` to the second `tikzpicture` environment. In your case, what was causing the problem was that you used `\only<1->` instead of the `\only<1-3>` for the first `tikzpicture`

Comment: @KevinC Yes, you are right. I should have used `\only<1-3>` instead of `only<1->`. Thank you for your suggestion.Now, the method you should also works perfect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The overlay specification `\only<1->{<text>}` causes `<text>` to appear on *all* slides from slide 1 on. If you want to restrict the appearance of `<text>` just to a particular range, you can use something like `\only<1,2,3>{<text>}` or, more easily, using a range as in `\only<1-3>{<text>}` (one can also use more complex specifications like `\only<1-3,5-7,9>{<text>}` which means that `<text>` will appear on slides `1` to `3`, `5` to `7` and `9`). Section **9 Creating Overlays** (particularly from the secons subsection on) contains the details for overlay specifications.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Age of Water under dye from all Rivers}

    \only<1-3>{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [](0,0)(start){ \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}};
%       \draw [step=0.5cm,thin,dotted] (-5,-4) grid(5,4);
%       \node [circle]at (-4.5,0){0};
%       \node [circle,radius=0.9cm,fill=red!30,] at (-4.5,0)(a){};
        \onslide<2->{\draw [red,fill=red!30](-4.3,-0.2)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-3.3,0)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-2.5,-0.7)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-4.,-0.8)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](-4.,-1.2)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](4.3,1.6)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](3.3,2.7)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](1.6,3.5)circle(0.1cm);
        \draw [red,fill=red!30](1.3,3.5)circle(0.1cm);}         
        \node [rectangle,text width=4cm,red] at (5.5,3) (return) {$Q_2 = 169 A^{0.616}$     \linebreak Mason et. al. 1998};
        \onslide<3> \node [rectangle,text width=4cm,red] at (5,0) (return) {Smaller near the source     \linebreak Increases away from the source};
        \onslide<3> \draw [red](-3.3,-1.5) circle(0.7cm);%wolf bay small age
    \end{tikzpicture}}

        \only<4->{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [](0,0)(start){ \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-b}};
    \draw [step=0.5,dotted](-5,-4) grid (5,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for the example I changed the clip commands; restore them in the actual code.

Comment: Awesome. That is exactly what I wanted. I am learning latex recently and trying to make a presentation so I am having very simple questions. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @Jdbaba You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. I'll add some explanation in a few minutes.