# Tikz animated figure in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations

If possible, can someone help me to animated this figure with `Tikz` in `Beamer`?

I updated starting by

```
1 : ( Yamada-watanab )
2: (Existence faible)
3: (unicite trajectorielle)
4: Tow edges frome  (Existence faible)  (unicite trajectorielle)
5: one Edge from  ( Yamada-watanab ) To (Existence Forte)
6: one Edge from (Existence Forte) to (Defintion) (left one )
7: one Edge from (defintion) (left one) To (Existence faible)
8: One Edge from (unicité trajectorielle) To (Defintion) ( right one)
8: One Edge from (Defintion) ( right one) To (unicité en loi)
9: (unicité en loi)
10: (Engelbert-Cherny) 
11: Tow Edge from (Existence Forte) and (Unicité en loi) To (Engelbert-Cherny)
12: One Edge from (Engelbert-Cherny) To (Unicté trajectorielle)
```

I tries to use package `animated` but failed:

```
\documentclass[leqno,mathserif]{beamer}  
\usepackage{graphics,bm}
\usetheme{Luebeck} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=7mm, row sep=5mm]{
                    \node (se) [draw,shape=rectangle] {Existence Forte}; \&
                    \node (yw) [draw,shape=circle] {Yamada-watanab}; \&
                    \node (ul) [draw,shape=rectangle] {Unicité en Loi}; \\
                    \node (d1) [draw,shape=circle] {Définition}; \& 
                    \&   
                    \node (d2) [draw, shape=circle] {Définition}; \\
                    \node (we) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Existence Faible}; \&
                    \node (ec) [draw, shape=circle] {Engelbert-Cherny}; \& 
                    \node (pu) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Unicité Trajectorielle}; \\
                };
                \draw[->, thick] (se) -- (d1); \draw[->, thick] (d1) -- (we);
                \draw[->, thick] (we) -- (yw); \draw[->, thick] (yw) -- (se);
                \draw[->, thick] (se) -- (ec); \draw[->, thick] (ul) -- (ec);
                \draw[->, thick] (ec) -- (pu); \draw[->, thick] (pu) -- (yw);
                \draw[->, thick] (pu) -- (d2); \draw[->, thick] (d2) -- (ul);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame} \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand your specifications. Shall each number be a consecutive animation step? Shall the objects from previous animation steps be hidden again? What exactly does *"to give"* mean?

Comment: Furthermore: What should happen to the edges. Shall they appear only if both, starting and ending node, are visible?

Comment: To get yourself started: Take a look at the `visible on` style defined in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step/55849#55849)

Comment: @Daniel thanks for ur time so I'll redefine specifications this time  with edges

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If by "animated" you mean creating overlays, then a straight application of Daniel's `visible on` key would solve the problem.

**Step 1.** Put the following in the preamble:

```
\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}
```

**Step 2.** Use the `[visible on=<num->]` to control the part of drawing you want to show on a particular slide. For example,

```
\node (se) [draw,shape=rectangle,visible on=<5->] {Existence Forte};
```

means node `(se)` will be shown from the fifth slide onwards.

The following should produce an overlay effect you wanted:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=7mm, row sep=5mm]{
        \node (se) [draw,shape=rectangle,visible on=<5->] {Existence Forte}; \&
        \node (yw) [draw,shape=circle,visible on=<1->] {Yamada-watanab}; \&
        \node (ul) [draw,shape=rectangle,visible on=<9->] {Unicité en Loi}; \\
        \node (d1) [draw,shape=circle,visible on=<6->] {Définition}; \& 
        \&   
        \node (d2) [draw, shape=circle,visible on=<8->] {Définition}; \\
        \node (we) [draw, shape=rectangle,visible on=<2->] {Existence Faible}; \&
        \node (ec) [draw, shape=circle,visible on=<10->] {Engelbert-Cherny}; \& 
        \node (pu) [draw, shape=rectangle,visible on=<3->] {Unicité Trajectorielle}; \\
    };
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<6->] (se) -- (d1); \draw[->, thick,visible on=<7->]  -- (we);
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<4->] (we) -- (yw); \draw[->, thick,visible on=<5->] (yw) -- (se);
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<11->] (se) -- (ec); \draw[->, thick,visible on=<11->] (ul) -- (ec);
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<12->] (ec) -- (pu); \draw[->, thick,visible on=<4->] (pu) -- (yw);
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<8->] (pu) -- (d2); \draw[->, thick,visible on=<9->] (d2) -- (ul);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you please post the full MWE on pastebin? additionally, how can I export the beamer presentation to gif? Thanks in advance

Comment: Daniel code is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/138900

Comment: If the nodes in the animation have labels, one maybe include `prefix after command={\pgfextra{\tikzset{every label/.style={opacity=0}}}}` in the definition of invisible to have the text hidden as well.

Comment: How can I make sure that the tikzpicture has the full size of the final picture from beginning on?

Comment: @kmundnic your comment would have the next that I'd ask. But where exactly do I need to put this?

Comment: @white_gecko in the preamble, inside the tikzset, when defining the invisible style:   invisible/.style={
   opacity=0,
   prefix after command={\pgfextra{\tikzset{every label/.style={opacity=0}}}}
  },