# Beamer overlays in tikz-network figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I would like to define overlays (in the Beamer sense) in figures designed using the [`tikz-network`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-network?lang=en) package.

For instance, say I have the following figure:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-network}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=0.0, y=1.0, label=$v_1$]{v1}
    \Vertex[x=1.0, y=1.0, label=$v_2$]{v2}
    \Vertex[x=2.0, y=1.0, label=$v_3$]{v3}

    \Edge[color=black](v1)(v2)
    \Edge[color=black](v2)(v3)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and that I want node `v1` to disappear at step 2. I have tried using the `visible on` key proposed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136166/31360 and which looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-network}

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=0.0, y=1.0, label=$v_1$, visible on=<2->]{v1}
    \Vertex[x=1.0, y=1.0, label=$v_2$]{v2}
    \Vertex[x=2.0, y=1.0, label=$v_3$]{v3}

    \Edge[color=black](v1)(v2)
    \Edge[color=black](v2)(v3)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But it does not seem to work with `tikz-network`, as I get a `"Package xkeyval Error: 'on visible' undefined in families 'vertex'`" error. I guess the solution is to extend the key to `vertex` (and to `edge` as well), but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Please add a full compileable code.

Comment: Sorry, I completed my question.

Comment: To make use of `\alt`, you need in one way or another involve `beamer`. And you need to switch to the `tikz` directory with `\Vertex[x=0.0, y=1.0, label=$v_1$,style={visible on=<2->}]{v1}`.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to include the beamer code when I wrote the minimal example, my bad. I fixed that in the question. About your above solution: it works fine...except for the text, which is still displayed when the rest of the node isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing the `tikz-network` package, I don't know if it is possible to adapt the `visible on` style for `tikz-network`. Nevertheless, it is still possible to use the classic controls for overlaying with beamer.

To do this, you must place yourself in a frame environment (which you have forgotten). The commands `\onslide` and `\only` are identical except that `\onslide` reserves the place of what it does not display.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-network}

%  \tikzset{
%    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
%    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
%    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
%      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
%    },
%  }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \onslide<1->{\Vertex[x=0.0, y=1.0, label=$v_1$]{v1}}
    \onslide<2->{\Vertex[x=1.0, y=1.0, label=$v_2$]{v2}}
    \onslide<3->{\Vertex[x=2.0, y=1.0, label=$v_3$]{v3}}

    \only<2->{\Edge[color=black](v1)(v2)}
    \only<3>{\Edge[color=black](v2)(v3)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: Indeed, I had forgotten to put the figure in a beamer document in my question. I have corrected that. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

*If* you switch to `beamer`, you can make of the `\alt` command that the Ti*k*Z styles you are trying to employ are using. Unfortunately, `tikz-network` has its own keys for opacity, so you could do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-network}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A network}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
    \alt<2->{}{\def\VertexFillOpacity{0}\def\VertexLineOpacity{0}
    \def\VertexTextOpacity{0}}
    \Vertex[x=0.0, y=1.0, label=$v_1$]{v1}
    \end{scope}
    \Vertex[x=1.0, y=1.0, label=$v_2$]{v2}
    \Vertex[x=2.0, y=1.0, label=$v_3$]{v3}

    \Edge[color=black](v1)(v2)
    \Edge[color=black](v2)(v3)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, with the edge also disappearing and a style.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\tikzset{
  network invisible/.code={\def\VertexFillOpacity{0}\def\VertexLineOpacity{0}\def\VertexTextOpacity{0}
  \def\EdgeOpacity{0}\def\EdgeTextFillOpacity{0}\def\EdgeTextOpacity{0}},
  network visible on/.code={\alt#1{}{\tikzset{network invisible}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A network}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[network visible on=<2->]
      \Vertex[x=0.0, y=1.0, label=$v_1$]{v1}
    \end{scope}
    \Vertex[x=1.0, y=1.0, label=$v_2$]{v2}
    \Vertex[x=2.0, y=1.0, label=$v_3$]{v3}
    \begin{scope}[network visible on=<2->]
    \Edge[color=black](v1)(v2)
    \end{scope}
    \Edge[color=black](v2)(v3)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Let me also mention that the `visible on` style was invented for a reason: you can use the vertices in paths even when they are not shown, and you are not haunted by jumps in the slides.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do not need to draw paths, so I think I'll use AndréC's solution, though, as I find it is less verbose.

Comment: @VincentLabatut `tikz-network` adds a lot of paths, so sooner or later you may experience jumps. There is a very long analogous story in the context of ordinary `tikzpicture`s.