# Tikz animated figure in Beamer with node with label

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations

I want to achieve the same result as for the question: [Tikz animated figure in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136143/tikz-animated-figure-in-beamer)

The difference in my case is, that I use labels in my nodes. For nodes there is already a solution in the comment by @kmundnic: [Tikz animated figure in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136143/tikz-animated-figure-in-beamer#comment1322349_136166)

But in my special case I have newlines in the labels, which results in the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.16 \end{frame}
                
?
```

My MWE to reproduce the error is:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0,prefix after command={\pgfextra{\tikzset{every label/.style={opacity=0}}}}},
  visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.style={align=center}]
  \path (1,1) node[draw, shape=circle, text width=2.2cm, visible on=<2->, label=center:{Label\\new Line}] (LODL2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you just leave out the `\\` it will compile.

*Edit:** added `every label/.style={align=center}` to tikzpicture which is needed to compile the MWE without the animation part.

*Edit2:** putting the label into the node, so far is no solution, as the amount of text make the node bigger:

```
  \path (1,1) node[draw, shape=circle, text width=2.2cm, align=center, label=center:{Label\\new Line}] (LODL1) {};
  \path (4,1) node[draw, shape=circle, text width=2.2cm, visible on=<2->, align=center, label=center:{}] (LODL2) {Label\\new Line};
  \path (1,1) node[draw, shape=circle, text width=2.2cm, visible on=<3->, align=center, label=center:{}] (LODL2) {Label\\new Line};
```

In this image, first the node is drawn as I want it at `(1,1)`, then two nodes are drawn at `(4,1)` and `(1,1)` with the label in the node. As one can see the second and third node is bigger than the first node. The more text, the bigger the circle.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two *nodes* and `\onslide`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.style={align=center}]

    \path (1,1) node[draw, shape=circle, text width=2.2cm] (LODL2) {};
\onslide<2>{
    \path (1,1) node[ shape=circle, text width=2.2cm, label=center:{Label\\new Line}] {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This brought me to the solution, there is no need for `visible on=` i just hide/reveal the nodes with `\uncover{}` which works great. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This works if you put the text into the `node` itself without the need for the `prefix after command` command.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0,%prefix after command={\pgfextra{\tikzset{every label/.style={opacity=0}}}}
  },
  visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \path (1,1) node[draw, shape=circle, text width=2.2cm, visible on=<2->,align=center] (LODL2) {Label\\ new Line};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this does not solve the problem. When I add the label into the node itself the circle gets bigger, when I add more text. But I want to keep the size of the circle, as it is independent of the amount of text in the label.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "gets bigger" since the first slide doesn't show any circles. What may be making the circle bigger is the `text width=2.2cm` parameter you added to the code.

Comment: I've tried to illustrate the issue with the label in the node in my second edit.