# Appearing bullet points and parts of tikz drawing at the same time

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations

I struggle to get the following working. I would like to animate a tikz pictue and bullet points at the same time, i.e. the first bullet point appears with the first part of the drawing, then the second bullet point appears with the second part of the drawing and so on.

[Following this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136143/tikz-animated-figure-in-beamer) I was able to make the tikz animation working, and using `\pause` I can make the bullet point animation working, but I am not able to join them together.

The code I am experimenting with at the moment (mostly taken from the linked question):

```
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \pause
        \item B
        \pause
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=7mm, row sep=5mm]{
        \node (se) [draw,shape=rectangle,visible on=<5->] {Existence Forte}; \&
        \node (yw) [draw,shape=circle,visible on=<1->] {Yamada-watanab}; \&
        \node (ul) [draw,shape=rectangle,visible on=<9->] {Unicité en Loi}; \\
        \node (d1) [draw,shape=circle,visible on=<6->] {Définition}; \& 
        \&   
        \node (d2) [draw, shape=circle,visible on=<8->] {Définition}; \\
        \node (we) [draw, shape=rectangle,visible on=<2->] {Existence Faible}; \&
        \node (ec) [draw, shape=circle,visible on=<10->] {Engelbert-Cherny}; \& 
        \node (pu) [draw, shape=rectangle,visible on=<3->] {Unicité Trajectorielle}; \\
    };
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<6->] (se) -- (d1); \draw[->, thick,visible on=<7->]  -- (we);
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<4->] (we) -- (yw); \draw[->, thick,visible on=<5->] (yw) -- (se);
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<11->] (se) -- (ec); \draw[->, thick,visible on=<11->] (ul) -- (ec);
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<12->] (ec) -- (pu); \draw[->, thick,visible on=<4->] (pu) -- (yw);
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<8->] (pu) -- (d2); \draw[->, thick,visible on=<9->] (d2) -- (ul);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

To be specific, let's say I want the A bullet point appear at the third animation step and B at the fifth one. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlay specifications work for list items as well, so you can do e.g.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<3-> Appears at third frame
        \item<5-> Appears at fifth frame
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```