# Beamer overlay specifications for a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

Overlay specifications can be added to the TikZ commands.

```
\node<2> (a) {only visible on slide 2};
```

Is this also possible for the whole tikzpicture environment?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[<2>]
  \node (a) {only visible on slide 2};
  \node (b) {also only visible on slide 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This can be emulated by enclosing the environment in `\only<2>{ ... }` but this is impossible when the `tikzpicture` is used in a `\newenvironment`.

Comment: A quick solution is to include `\only<2>` in the definition of your new environment, unless you have a more specific example in mind that doesn't work with this strategy.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 22):

As usual, these problems can be easily solved thanks to the style `visible on` defined by Daniel (see [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step#55849)).

Moreover, it works without problems with custom environments. Demonstration:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

 \tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\newenvironment{mytikz}[1][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]}{\end{tikzpicture}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[visible on=<2->]
  \node at (0,0) (a) {only visible on slide 2};
  \node at (2,2) (b) {also only visible on slide 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

Some text here:
\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\end{itemize}

\begin{center}
\begin{mytikz}[visible on=<3>]
 \draw[top color=orange,bottom color=magenta!80!purple]
 (0,0) rectangle(2,1);
 \draw[top color=magenta!80!purple,bottom color=green,radius=0.5]
 (4,0.5) circle ;
\end{mytikz}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]