# Beamer \pause in tikz flowchart causing crash

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, errors, flow-charts, pause

everyone. Im using TexStudio with Texlive and pdfLatex compiler for this proejct. I want the flowcharts to be divided into 3 parts by \pasue, to show them in some order.

The code without \pause works fine

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{icomma} 
\usepackage{array,tabularx,tabulary,booktabs} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\subsection{Test pause}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\insertsection} 
    \framesubtitle{\insertsubsection}

    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.multipart}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
    \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm
    ,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
    \tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
    \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered,
    draw=black, fill=orange!30]
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered,
    draw=black, fill=green!30]
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \scalebox{0.4}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, scale
            =0.3]
                \node (start) [startstop] {Начало};
                \node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Ввод a,b};
                \draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
                \node (dec1) [decision, below of=in1, yshift
                =-0.5cm] {a=b};
                \node (dec2) [decision, below of=dec1, yshift
                =-0.5cm] {a>b};
                \node (pro2a) [process, left of=dec2, xshift
                =-2cm, below of=dec2, yshift
                =-0.5cm] {a:=a-b};
                \node (pro2b) [process, right of=dec2, xshift
                =2cm, below of=dec2, yshift
                =-0.5cm] {b:=b-a};
                \node (out1) [io, below of=dec2, yshift=-4cm] {Вывод a};
                \node (stop) [startstop, below of=out1] {
                Конец};
                \draw [arrow] (in1) -- (dec1);
                \path (in1) -- (dec1) coordinate[midway] (aux);;
                \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=east] {
                Нет} (dec2);
                \draw [arrow] (dec2) -| node[anchor=south] {
                Да} (pro2a);
                \draw [arrow] (dec2) -| node[anchor=south] {
                Нет} (pro2b);
                \draw [arrow] (pro2b) |- ([xshift=-6.5cm, yshift=-1.5cm]pro2a.south) |- (aux);
                \draw [arrow] (pro2a) |- ([xshift=-6.5cm, yshift=-1.5cm]pro2a.south) |- (aux);
                \draw [arrow] (dec1.east) -| node[anchor=south] {
                Да} ([xshift=6.5cm, yshift=-3.5cm]pro2b.south) -| (out1);
                \draw [arrow] (out1) -- (stop);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        \end{tabular}
        & \begin{tabular}{l}
        \parbox{0.4\linewidth}{
             \textbf{Flowchart of GCD} some text
            }  
         \end{tabular}  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But when i add \pause lets say after `\node (out1) [io, below of=dec2, yshift=-4cm] {Вывод a};` compile process exits with errors. This is one of them: **Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/trapezium left angle', to which you passed '70', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \end{frame}**

Comment: Welcome! Try adding `[fragile]` after `\begin{frame}`. (Off-topic: please avoid `\tikzstyle`. Please use the `positioning` library with its syntax. And so on.)

Comment: You can put \pause between two tikzpictures, but not inside one.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146908/beamer-overlay-specifications-for-a-tikzpicture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, if this can help you:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                    chains,
                    positioning,
                    shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{FlowChart/.style={
     base/.style = {draw, minimum width=18mm, minimum height=5mm, 
                    align=center, font=\small},
startstop/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=red!30},
  process/.style = {base, fill=orange!30},
 decision/.style = {base, diamond, aspect=2},
       io/.style = {base, trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                    fill=blue!30, 
                    text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
                    },
      arr/.style = {semithick,-Triangle}
        }   }

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\subsection{Test pause}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{\insertsection}
    \framesubtitle{\insertsubsection}
\begin{tabular}{l p{0.3\linewidth}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart, baseline=(current bounding box.center),
node distance = 5mm and 3mm,
  start chain = going below,
   chn/.style = {on chain, join=by arr},
   lbl/.style = {font=\footnotesize}
                        ]
    \onslide+<1->
\node (start)   [startstop,chn] {Start};            % Начало
\node (in1)     [io,chn] {Input a,b};               % Ввод
    \onslide+<2->
\node (dec1)    [decision,chn]  {$a=b$ ?};
\node (dec2)    [decision,chn]  {$a>b$ ?};
\path (dec1) -- node[lbl, right] {No} (dec2);   % Нет
    \onslide+<3->
\node (pro2a)   [process, below  left=of dec2] {$a\colon=a-b$};
\draw[arr]  (dec2.west) node[lbl, above  left] {Yes} -| (pro2a);% Дa
    \onslide+<4->
\node (pro2b)   [process, below right=of dec2] {$b\colon=b-a$};
\draw[arr]  (dec2.east) node[lbl, above right] {No}  -| (pro2b);% Нет
    \onslide+<5->
\node (out1)    [io, below=of dec2 |- pro2a.south] {Input a};   % Вывод
\node (stop)    [startstop, below=of out1] {Stop};              % Конец
%
\coordinate[right=of pro2b] (aux); 
\draw[arr]  (dec1.east) node[lbl, above right] {Yes}            % Дa
            -| (aux) |- (out1);
\draw[arr]  (out1) -- (stop);
    \end{tikzpicture}
         &   \textbf{Flowchart of GCD} some text
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

- In above MWE are used `\onslide` instead of `\pause`.
- For styles is define style `Flowchart` using `tikzset`.
- In drawing of flowchart is used TikZ library `chains` which enable simplified diagram code
- Since I haven't Russian fonts, I translate Russian text to English
- The first slide:

[image]

- The last slide:

[image: WE]

Comment: Thanks, that worked out well.

Comment: @Andrew, you are welcome!