# Overlaying a tikzpicture on beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles, overlays

I am trying to use an overlay system on a beamer slide in order to display successively several images.

I start by displaying a blank box containing some text (using `\itemize`) then I add an associated image for each sentence printed in the box (displayed just under the box).

The first image is a `\tikzpicture` image and after that I use classical png images.

The problem is that if I start displaying the images after the tikzpicture I keep having them in a strange position (on the far right of the frame) like this :

[image]

The tikzpicture itself is well positioned but other images are constantly shifted and I don't know why.

I have used several methods to overlay the tikzfigure : the one used here is `\onlyenv` but I have also tried to implement the solution provided in the post :
[Beamer overlay specifications for a tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146908/beamer-overlay-specifications-for-a-tikzpicture)

But I keep having the same exact problem of positioning : how can I get rid of this ?

Thank you very much,

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

%%%%%% ENCODAGE %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%% TIKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors,norndcorners]{hf-tikz}

%%%%%% OTHERS %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{listings,stackengine}
\def\doubleunderline#1{\underline{\underline{#1}}}

% FONT SIZE %
\makeatletter
\newcommand\thefontsize{The current font size is: \f@size pt}
\makeatother
\usepackage{epstopdf} %Convertir en PDF


\author{XXX}
\title{XXX}
\subtitle{XXX}
\institute [XXX] {XXX \\ XXX}
\date{\today}

%%%%%% DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}


%%%%%% BOX %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{subcaption}



%%%%%% PGFPLOTS %%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gaussian}{2}
{%
    \pgfmathparse{(1/(#1 * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp((-1 / 2) * (((x - #2)/#1) ^ 2))}%
}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mean}{7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\std}{0.3}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\definecolor{BgYellow}{HTML}{FFF59C}
\definecolor{FrameYellow}{HTML}{F7A600}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, matrix, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta,
                patterns.meta
                }

%%%%%%%CADRES DES EQUATIONS%%%%%
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,colframe=red,colback=red!10!white,boxsep=0pt,sharp corners,
equal height group=C,
minimum for equal height group=C:1.5cm,
valign=center,
}}

%%%%%%%DOCUMENT%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]

\begin{tcolorbox}[title = Perspectives futures, ams nodisplayskip,colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black]
\begin{itemize}
\vskip0.3cm
\item<1-> Le cas de la coalescence de 2 gouttes élastiques 
\item<3-> La formation de "doigts" avec des gouttes élastiques sur un plan incliné
\item<5-> L'origine des "plis" de la laccolithe à creuser
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{center}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={gauss(\x)=3*exp(-(\x/3.25)^2);},
  scale = 0.6,
  s/.style={shift=(0:16)}]
\fill [cyan!20]
          plot[domain= 0:8, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)})
  {[s] -- plot[domain=-8:0, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)})
       |- (-8,0)}
       -| cycle;

\filldraw[fill=pink!20, thick]
          plot[domain=0:8, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)})
  {[s] -- plot[domain=-8:0, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)})
       -- plot[domain=0:-8, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)+0.6})}
       -- plot[domain=8:0, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)+0.6})
       -- cycle;
% \draw[very thick] (0:8) -- ++ (up:.6);
\path[fill=cyan!20] (0,-2) -- (0,0) -- (0.85,0) -- (0.85,-2) -- (0,-2);
\path[fill=cyan!20] (16,-2) -- (16,0) -- (15.15,0) -- (15.15,-2) -- (16,-2);
\draw[black,thick] (0.85,-2) -- (0.85,0) -- (15.15,0) -- (15.15,-2);
\draw [yshift=-0.25cm, -stealth](0.425,-1.5) -- node [fill=cyan!20,scale=0.55] {$Q_1$} (0.425,0);
\draw [yshift=-0.25cm, -stealth](15.575,-1.5) -- node [fill=cyan!20,scale=0.55] {$Q_2$} (15.575,0);
\fill[pattern = north east lines] (-0.4,-2.25) -- (-0.4,{gauss(0)+0.625}) -- (0,{gauss(0)+0.625}) -- (0,-2.25) -- (-0.4,-2.25);
\fill[pattern = north east lines] (16.4,-2.25) -- (16.4,{gauss(0)+0.625}) -- (16,{gauss(0)+0.625}) -- (16,-2.25) -- (16.4,-2.25);
%\draw[fill=gray!20] (0.85,-1.5) -- (0.85,0) -- (15.15,0) -- (15.15,-1.5) -- (0.85,-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<4>
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \includegraphics[height= 0.5\textheight,width=0.6 \textwidth]{example-image}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<6>
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \includegraphics[height= 0.5\textheight,width=0.6 \textwidth]{example-image}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{center}
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\includegraphics` is not a tikz command. It is not necessary or useful to warp the in a `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

%%%%%% ENCODAGE %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%% TIKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors,norndcorners]{hf-tikz}

%%%%%% OTHERS %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{listings,stackengine}
\def\doubleunderline#1{\underline{\underline{#1}}}

% FONT SIZE %
\makeatletter
\newcommand\thefontsize{The current font size is: \f@size pt}
\makeatother
\usepackage{epstopdf} %Convertir en PDF


\author{XXX}
\title{XXX}
\subtitle{XXX}
\institute [XXX] {XXX \\ XXX}
\date{\today}

%%%%%% DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}


%%%%%% BOX %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{subcaption}



%%%%%% PGFPLOTS %%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gaussian}{2}
{%
    \pgfmathparse{(1/(#1 * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp((-1 / 2) * (((x - #2)/#1) ^ 2))}%
}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mean}{7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\std}{0.3}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\definecolor{BgYellow}{HTML}{FFF59C}
\definecolor{FrameYellow}{HTML}{F7A600}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, matrix, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta,
                patterns.meta
                }

%%%%%%%CADRES DES EQUATIONS%%%%%
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,colframe=red,colback=red!10!white,boxsep=0pt,sharp corners,
equal height group=C,
minimum for equal height group=C:1.5cm,
valign=center,
}}

%%%%%%%DOCUMENT%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]

\begin{tcolorbox}[title = Perspectives futures, ams nodisplayskip,colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black]
\begin{itemize}
\vskip0.3cm
\item<1-> Le cas de la coalescence de 2 gouttes élastiques 
\item<3-> La formation de "doigts" avec des gouttes élastiques sur un plan incliné
\item<5-> L'origine des "plis" de la laccolithe à creuser
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{center}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={gauss(\x)=3*exp(-(\x/3.25)^2);},
  scale = 0.6,
  s/.style={shift=(0:16)}]
\fill [cyan!20]
          plot[domain= 0:8, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)})
  {[s] -- plot[domain=-8:0, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)})
       |- (-8,0)}
       -| cycle;

\filldraw[fill=pink!20, thick]
          plot[domain=0:8, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)})
  {[s] -- plot[domain=-8:0, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)})
       -- plot[domain=0:-8, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)+0.6})}
       -- plot[domain=8:0, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)+0.6})
       -- cycle;
% \draw[very thick] (0:8) -- ++ (up:.6);
\path[fill=cyan!20] (0,-2) -- (0,0) -- (0.85,0) -- (0.85,-2) -- (0,-2);
\path[fill=cyan!20] (16,-2) -- (16,0) -- (15.15,0) -- (15.15,-2) -- (16,-2);
\draw[black,thick] (0.85,-2) -- (0.85,0) -- (15.15,0) -- (15.15,-2);
\draw [yshift=-0.25cm, -stealth](0.425,-1.5) -- node [fill=cyan!20,scale=0.55] {$Q_1$} (0.425,0);
\draw [yshift=-0.25cm, -stealth](15.575,-1.5) -- node [fill=cyan!20,scale=0.55] {$Q_2$} (15.575,0);
\fill[pattern = north east lines] (-0.4,-2.25) -- (-0.4,{gauss(0)+0.625}) -- (0,{gauss(0)+0.625}) -- (0,-2.25) -- (-0.4,-2.25);
\fill[pattern = north east lines] (16.4,-2.25) -- (16.4,{gauss(0)+0.625}) -- (16,{gauss(0)+0.625}) -- (16,-2.25) -- (16.4,-2.25);
%\draw[fill=gray!20] (0.85,-1.5) -- (0.85,0) -- (15.15,0) -- (15.15,-1.5) -- (0.85,-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<4>
%\begin{tikzpicture}
    \includegraphics[height= 0.5\textheight,width=0.6 \textwidth]{example-image}
%\end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<6>
%\begin{tikzpicture}
    \includegraphics[height= 0.5\textheight,width=0.6 \textwidth]{example-image}
%\end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{center}
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the correction ! In fact I was trying to write something like : `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,] 
        \begin{onlyenv}<1>
                \node[above=1.0cm, anchor= south,xshift= 1cm] at (current page.south) {
                \subfloat[\centering Caption ]{{\includegraphics[height = 0.275\textheight, width=0.275\linewidth ]{example-image} }}
            };
        \end{onlyenv} \end{tikzpicture}` This is why I have wrapped the image in tikzpicture

Comment: @Wiss That's equally unnecessary.

Comment: Yes : thank you !