# Leave certain part of a tikz-picture uncovered

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

i have a picture with three circles, see the minimal working example below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,0) circle (1);
\pause
\draw (5,0) circle (1);
\draw (10,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For certain reasons, i would like to show only the first circle with a continous lins, the other circles should be visible in a semitransparent way. By using the "\pause"-command, i get an image exactly in the way i would like to have it on the first slide, but i do not want the second slide to be generated (because here all three circles are fully visible again).

Is there an option / certain command in order to "highlight" just a certain part of a whole picture? In other words, is there an option for fading out certain areas of an image?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: Take a look into this approach: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/3751

Comment: I don't understand _"By using the "\pause"-command, i get an image exactly in the way i would like to have it on the first slide, but i do not want the second slide to be generated (because here all three circles are fully visible again)."_ So, you want to display on the first slide one circle and on the second one all the circles, where two of them are transparent?

Comment: I just want to have 1 slide, where the first circle should be totally visible and all others should be semitransparent

Comment: @pythag0ra5: Hence, no need of overlays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you could just put the two last circles in a `scope` and set `opacity=0.3` (adjust the value to whatever you like).

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,0) circle (1);
\begin{scope}[opacity=0.3] % sets opacity to 30% for everything in the scope
\draw (5,0) circle (1);
\draw (10,0) circle (1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: In case _overlays_ would have been needed to display transparent circles on slide 2, I suggest the use of [`aobs-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz). Just need to change options to the `scope` environment: `\begin{scope}[background aspect={opacity=0.4},aspect on=<2>]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one over kill with `fadings` library:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade left,
            left color=transparent!10,
            right color=transparent!10]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,0) circle (1);
\draw (5,0) circle (1);
\draw (10,0) circle (1);
\fill[white,path fading=fade left] (3.9,-1.1) rectangle (11.1,1.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here we can have a gradual fading by adjusting:

```
\tikzfading[name=fade left,
            left color=transparent!60,
            right color=transparent!10]
```

say. This gives:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade left,
            left color=transparent!60,
            right color=transparent!10]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,0) circle (1);
\draw (5,0) circle (1);
\draw (10,0) circle (1);
\fill[white,path fading=fade left] (3.9,-1.1) rectangle (11.1,1.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found on p.234 of TikZ/PGF manual: transparency. There are several ways to implement this. A simple one follows.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,0) circle (1);
\pause
\draw [draw opacity=0.3](5,0) circle (1);
\draw [draw opacity=0.3](10,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If the drawing becomes more complicated, perhaps it would be better to put the opacity into a style?

Comment: The `\pause` is unnecessary.