# Beamer/TikZ/PGF: Applying a key only for one slide (similar to uncover or only)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I want that a key that is only applied in specific slides/frames just like `uncover` or `only`. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=orange] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \uncover<1>{\node at (2,0) [anchor=west] {1};}
    \uncover<2>{\node at (2,0) [anchor=west] {2 -- should be only orange here};}
    \uncover<3>{\node at (2,0) [anchor=west] {3};}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Problem**

I want for example that the fill key is only applied to the second frame - something like this: `fill=<2>orange`.

I tried to understand [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step) related question but the code of the accepted answer is too complicated for me. But I guess it has something to do with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define a style that uses overlay specifications:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [onslide=<2>{fill=orange}] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \uncover<1>{\node at (2,0) [anchor=west] {1};}
    \uncover<2>{\node at (2,0) [anchor=west] {2 -- should be only orange here};}
    \uncover<3>{\node at (2,0) [anchor=west] {3};}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But why can't I just write `\draw [\only<#2>{fill=orange}] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);´

Comment: @ManuelKuehner because the TikZ parser expects to see valid keys inside the brackets and `\only` is not a valid TikZ key; defining the style solves the problem, as now the `onslide` style is a valid key.

Comment: Thanks again. So \only is valid when I put it in a style but not when I use it directly. Isn't that strange?

Comment: @ManuelKuehner when you define a style using `.code args`, the definition you put in is actually (nearly) arbitrary LaTeX code, and thus you can use `\only` there. But the stuff you put in square brackets following `\draw` cannot just be anything. It has to be the name of a style. (A PGF key, technically.)

Answer (score 2):

A particularly straightforward way to do this is to just use `\tikzset` inside `\only`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \only<2>{\tikzset{every path/.style={fill=orange}}}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \uncover<1>{\node at (2,0) [anchor=west] {1};}
    \uncover<2>{\node at (2,0) [anchor=west] {2 -- should be only orange here};}
    \uncover<3>{\node at (2,0) [anchor=west] {3};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could define an overlay-aware version of `\tikzset`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand<>\tikzset[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal{\tikzset}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset<2>{every path/.style={fill=orange}}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \uncover<1>{\node at (2,0) [anchor=west] {1};}
    \uncover<2>{\node at (2,0) [anchor=west] {2 -- should be only orange here};}
    \uncover<3>{\node at (2,0) [anchor=west] {3};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

Both versions are functionally the same, but the latter is slightly more convenient if you have to use it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using the [`aobs-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) package that defines apposite TikZ styles for overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [background fill=orange,fill on=<2>] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \node[visible on=<1>] at (2,0) [anchor=west] {1};
    \node[visible on=<2>]  at (2,0) [anchor=west] {2 -- should be only orange here};
    \node[visible on=<3>]  at (2,0) [anchor=west] {3};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @ManuelKuehner: you're welcome! :)