# Showing filled graphs from pgfplots, slide by slide with beamer

Tags: beamer, pgfplots

I want to uncover two plots one at a time using a combination of `beamer` and `pgfplots`. The MWE below highlights three attempts.

- The first attempt uses `\onslide` but doesn't seem to have any noticable effect, the final picture is directly displayed.
- The second atempt uses `\only` which sort of works, but since the second plot isn't considered in the bounds for the first plot's creation, we get a jump of some sort.
- Following [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/11162) I found the idea of `visible on` style. This looks promising, but it starts with the fill already there. Further it has four slides - which I don't understand why.

So my question is: how can one start with an empty axis and show one step at a time the two graphs and their respective fills.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Attempt 1}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}
        \onslide<+->{\addplot[black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2]{-x+3}\closedcycle;}
        \onslide<+->{\addplot[black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2]{x}\closedcycle;}
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Attempt 2}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}
        \only<+->{\addplot[black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2]{-x+3}\closedcycle;}
        \only<+->{\addplot[black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2]{x}\closedcycle;}
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Attempt 3}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[visible on=<+->, black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2]{-x+3}\closedcycle;
        \addplot[visible on=<+->, black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2]{x}\closedcycle;
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Attempt 3 works if you put `visible on=<+->` *after* the `fill opacity` option. The reason is that, in your MWE, the definition of `visible on` sets `opacity=0`, but this is overridden by `fill opacity=0.2`, which comes later. That's why the fills are already there, while the border lines are not.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Attempt 3}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2,visible on=<+->]{-x+3}\closedcycle;
        \addplot[black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2,visible on=<+->]{x}\closedcycle;
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: If the figure has legends that correspond to each curve all legends appear simultaneously in the begining

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possibility using your approach with `\only` and controlling `domain` and `ymin` for both plots:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Attempt 1}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-6]
        \only<+->{\addplot[black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2,domain=-5:5]{-x+3}\closedcycle;}
        \only<+->{\addplot[black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2,domain=-5:5]{x}\closedcycle;}
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]