# Visible on several intervals

Tags: beamer

I know that in tikz you can have a node shown on slide "16" using

`visible on=<16>`

and shown on all slides between 16 and 20 using

`visible on=<16-20>`

But how about having a node shown for a while, then not shown, and then shown again? Something like
`visible on=<16-20, 23-25>`?

Comment: this is beamer features rather than tikz

Comment: Please make a MWE that demonstrates where you get `visible on` from or how it is defined. It's neither default in tikz nor in beamer.

Comment: @samcarter I think it's this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step

Comment: @percusse yes that contains the answer it seems... one just has to use comma and extra {} braces.