# figure fade beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, presentations

Is there a way to have a transparent figure which can be made "solid" just like one can have a transperent block which can be made solid?

See figure
[image]

only the caption is made transparent and not the actual figure
code for generating the above figure

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Frankfurt}
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{t}
        test
    \end{block}
    %
    \pause
    \begin{block}{t}
        test
    \end{block}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width = 0.2\textheight]{example-image}
    \caption{1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}

\includegraphics[width = 0.2\textheight]{example-image}
\caption{2}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `visible on` style from [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/141947). Note the proposed style is now provided by the [`aobs-tikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) package.
Instead of setting `opacity` to `0` just set it to another value that fits your need (I do not know the default opacity that `beamer` uses.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0.3},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}

\newcommand{\includegraphicswithwisibility}[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[visible on={#1}] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[#2]{#3}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Frankfurt}
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{t}
    test
\end{block}
%
\pause
\begin{block}{t}
test
\end{block}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphicswithwisibility{<1->}{width = 0.2\textheight}{example-image}
\caption{1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}

\includegraphicswithwisibility{<2->}{width = 0.2\textheight}{example-image}
\caption{2}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To use the `aobs-tikz` functionnalities, replace

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0.3},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}
```

with

```
\usepackage{aobs-tikz}
\tikzset{invisible/.style={opacity=0.3}}
```

as `aobs-tikz` loads `tikz`. However the package defines the `invisible` style as `invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0}` hence the re-definition of the style.

Comment: How would the code look like if one had 2 x 2 figures where each figures has to be transparent and then to turn solid one by one?

Comment: Basically, you should use the `beamer` overlay options like `<*>` (see the documentation for more explainations). Short explaination if you want to see somenthing between visible between step `i` and step `j` type `<i-j>` first and last  may be omitted. For the 2*2 figure, you can use `subfigure` environments to place the graphics