# Replace TikZ's standard overlay specification from only to onslide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

In `beamer`, the standard overlay specification seems to be `onslide`. In below code, `\item<2->` reserves space for the second item on all slides. Inside a `tikz` environment, however, the standard overlay specification is `only`, which does not reserve space and causes these "jumping" or "dancing" slides. Is there a way to change the standard overlay specification to `onslide` so that the rest of the slide does not shift between slides 2 and 3?

I know I could use an `overlayarea` with sufficiently large height or, equivalently, draw an invisible rectangle on slides 1-2, but that requires manual effort that can accumulate to be quite costly in a lifetime of creating lecture slides. The `overlay` option for the `tikzpicture` has the desired effect only if there is no other content on the slide. I could use `\onslide<3->{\draw (0, 0) rectangle (-1, -1);}` instead, which has the desired effect, but is rather ugly. Is there no way to change the default behavior of the `\draw` and other beamer commands so that `\draw<> ...` produces `\onslide<>{\draw ...}`?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\draw<3-> (0, 0) rectangle (-1, -1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{itemize}
\item Some text
\item<2-> More text
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer, to a similar question help you at all: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/118712 Apparently it resulted in a package dedicated to doing what you seem to require: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz

Comment: Not quite. I suppose I am not asking how to achieve the effect. I know there are many ways that can do that, including many that I did not list in my post. I am simply wondering if there is a way to redefine the standard behavior in TikZ because that would be the cleanest solution of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Posting this as an answer in the hope that others will find it useful. `TikZ` resets the `\draw` and similar commands to `\path[draw]` in the beginning of every `tikzpicture` to prevent the user from accidentally overwriting it. This allows us to simply redefine `\draw` and others within an `every picture/.code`, checking whether there is an overlay specification with `\futurelet` and, if there is one, parsing it with `\def`. I think this solution should be quite robust and quite quick.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fixtikzpath}[1]{
    \expandafter\def\csname #1@standard@btkz\endcsname{\path[#1]}
    \expandafter\def\csname #1@gobble@btkz\endcsname<##1>##2;{
        \def\overlay@btkz{<##1>}
        \expandafter\onslide\overlay@btkz{\path[#1] ##2;}
    }
    \expandafter\def\csname #1@check@btkz\endcsname{
        \ifx\next@btkz<
            \expandafter\expandafter\csname #1@gobble@btkz\endcsname
        \else
            \expandafter\expandafter\csname #1@standard@btkz\endcsname
        \fi
    }
    \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{\expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\next@btkz\csname #1@check@btkz\endcsname}
}
\newcommand{\fixtikznode}{
    \def\node@standard@btkz{\tikz@path@overlay{node}}
    \def\node@gobble@btkz<##1>##2;{
        \def\overlay@btkz{<##1>}
        \expandafter\onslide\overlay@btkz{\tikz@path@overlay{node} ##2;}
    }
    \def\node@check@btkz{
        \ifx\next@btkz<
            \expandafter\node@gobble@btkz
        \else
            \expandafter\node@standard@btkz
        \fi
    }
    \def\node{\futurelet\next@btkz\node@check@btkz}
}
\tikzset{every picture/.code={
    \fixtikzpath{draw}
    \fixtikzpath{fill}
    \fixtikzpath{clip}
    \fixtikznode
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\draw<2-> (0, 0) rectangle (1.2, -1.2);
\fill<3-> (0, 0) rectangle (-1.4, -1.4);
\node<4-> at (-1.4, 1.4) {It works};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image][image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to use `\path` to replace the missing `\draw` features.  You can also use `[opacity=0]` for nodes or even an entire scope.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\draw<3-> (0, 0) rectangle (-1, -1);
\path (0, 0) rectangle (-1, -1);%***** added line *****
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{itemize}
\item Some text
\item<2-> More text
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was not looking for different ways of achieving the same result. Mostly, I was wondering why `onslide` is not the standard behavior in `tikz` and whether there is a way to patch that. It seems to be an odd choice to me since Till Tantau created both `tikz` and `beamer`, and `\onslide` is the standard for `beamer`.

Even though I am not looking for alternate ways to recreate the effect, this approach will not work if the drawn path is, say, `very thick`. Also, duplication of code is required. I'd say using `\onslide` explicitly or the `oabs-tikz` package are superior.

Comment: I suspect that oabs-tikz does automatically the same thing: running the code twice and saving the bounding box from the invisible run.

Comment: It's drawn with opacity 0 so stroke widths are accounted for.