# Elegant/Automated Way to Make My Single Framed Tikz Beamer in Multiple Frame

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles

I want this single framed beamer to reveal step by step in multiple frames

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetheme      {Warsaw}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

%
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
%
\usepackage{tikz,tgtermes,float}% times is deprecated - use one of the other options
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\definecolor{mypink3}{cmyk}{0, 0.7808, 0.4429, 0.1412}
\definecolor{yel}{rgb}{0.898, 0.6196, 0.14}
\definecolor{blue1}{rgb}{0.11, 0.5, 0.9}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test with bricks}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, transform shape, % <---
            line join=round]%,trim left={(-3,0)}, trim right={(5.5,0)}] 
            \path [
            mindmap,
            every node/.append style={text=white},
            level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=180, sibling angle=30, font=\large\sffamily\bfseries},
        level 2 concept/.append style={level distance=90, font=\sffamily\bfseries},
        concept color=yel!90!black,
        ]
        node [concept, font=\Huge\sffamily\bfseries, ball color=yel!90!black,  inner sep=10] (Mother of Mothers) {Mother of Mothers}[counterclockwise from=70] 
        
        child [concept color=mypink3!90!black] {
                node [concept, inner sep=10, ball color=mypink3!90!black] (Mother 1) {Mother 1}
                child[grow=75, concept color=blue1!90!black] {
                    node [concept,  inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 11) {Child 1, 1}
                } 
                child [grow=75, clockwise from=45, concept color=blue1!90!black ] {
                    node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 12) {Child 1, 2}
                }
                child [grow=75, clockwise from=149, concept color=blue1!140!black ] {
                    node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 13) {Child 1, 3}
                }
            }
        child [concept color=mypink3!90!black] {
                node [concept,  inner sep=10, ball color=mypink3!90!black] (Mother 2) {Mother 2}
                child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=60] {
                    node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 21) {Child 2, 1}
                }
                child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=103] {
                    node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 22) {Child 2, 2}
                }
            }
        child [concept color=mypink3!90!black] {
                node [concept,  inner sep=10, ball color=mypink3!90!black] (Mother 3) {Mother 3}
                child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=130] {
                    node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 31) {Child 3, 1}
                }
                child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=171] {
                    node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 32) {Child 32}
                }
                child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=87] {
                    node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 33) {Child 3, 3}
                }
            }
        child [concept color=mypink3!90!black] {
                node [concept,  inner sep=10, ball color=mypink3!90!black] (Mother 4) {Mother 4}
                [counterclockwise from=180]
                child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=150] {
                    node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 41) {Child 4,1}
                }
                child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=195] {
                    node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 42) {Child 4,2}
                    }
                }
            ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: The sigle framed beamer here]

I want it to look like [the first answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step)

in this [image: GIF PICTURE]

Comment: Well, the answer you linked to does exactly what you want, does it not? So, why not use it? What do you need in addition?

Comment: I have tried it with the function `tikset at the preamble which results in error

Comment: I just tried it, and it works for me. Make sure to copy the entire `tikzset` and add the `visible on` to the `child` options and not the `node` options.

Comment: Thanks, it works

Answer (score 2):

I write this as an answer with credit to @Markus G. He/she directed me on what to do through his comments and I find it useful. For record purpose and for who may search for such solution as this.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetheme      {Warsaw}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

%
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
%
\usepackage{tikz,tgtermes,float}% times is deprecated - use one of the other options
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\definecolor{mypink3}{cmyk}{0, 0.7808, 0.4429, 0.1412}
\definecolor{yel}{rgb}{0.898, 0.6196, 0.14}
\definecolor{blue1}{rgb}{0.11, 0.5, 0.9}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
        \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test with bricks}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, transform shape, % <---
            line join=round]%,trim left={(-3,0)}, trim right={(5.5,0)}] 
            \path [
            mindmap,
            every node/.append style={text=white},
            level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=180, sibling angle=30, font=\large\sffamily\bfseries},
        level 2 concept/.append style={level distance=90, font=\sffamily\bfseries},
        concept color=yel!90!black,
        ]
        node [concept, font=\Huge\sffamily\bfseries, ball color=yel!90!black,  inner sep=10] (Mother of Mothers) {Mother of Mothers}[counterclockwise from=70] 
        
        child [concept color=mypink3!90!black, visible on=<2->] {
            node [concept, inner sep=10, ball color=mypink3!90!black] (Mother 1) {Mother 1}
            child[grow=75, concept color=blue1!90!black, visible on=<3->] {
                node [concept,  inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 11) {Child 1, 1}
            } 
            child [grow=75, clockwise from=45, concept color=blue1!90!black, visible on=<4-> ] {
                node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 12) {Child 1, 2}
            }
            child [grow=75, clockwise from=149, concept color=blue1!140!black, visible on=<5-> ] {
                node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 13) {Child 1, 3}
            }
        }
        child [concept color=mypink3!90!black, visible on=<6->] {
            node [concept,  inner sep=10, ball color=mypink3!90!black] (Mother 2) {Mother 2}
            child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=60, visible on=<7->] {
                node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 21) {Child 2, 1}
            }
            child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=103, visible on=<8->] {
                node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 22) {Child 2, 2}
            }
        }
        child [concept color=mypink3!90!black, visible on=<9->] {
            node [concept,  inner sep=10, ball color=mypink3!90!black] (Mother 3) {Mother 3}
            child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=130, visible on=<10->] {
                node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 31) {Child 3, 1}
            }
            child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=171, visible on=<11->] {
                node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 32) {Child 32}
            }
            child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=87, visible on=<12->] {
                node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 33) {Child 3, 3}
            }
        }
        child [concept color=mypink3!90!black, visible on=<13->] {
            node [concept,  inner sep=10, ball color=mypink3!90!black] (Mother 4) {Mother 4}
            [counterclockwise from=180]
                child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=150, visible on=<14->] {
                    node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 41) {Child 4,1}
                }
                child [concept color=blue1!90!black, grow=195, visible on=<15->] {
                    node [concept, inner sep=5, ball color=blue1!90!black] (Child 42) {Child 4,2}
                }
            }
            ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Here is the output in .GIF]

Comment: Actually, there was a reason, why I did not give this as an answer and that is bascially that this is not really my answer, I just pointed out how to implement someone elses solution (namely @Daniel, who came up with the original answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/118712 ). Also, in terms of pronouns: he/him is fine.