# How to insert an image in the middle of an step-by-step revealed Mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, mindmaps

I would like to insert a slide to show an image while revealing a TikZ Mindmap.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=7}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shadows} 
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step
\tikzset{ 
    invisible/.style={opacity=0.1},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }
%%%---------------
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%---------------------
% \usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{standalone}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=7}
\begin{document}
            \begin{frame}[t]{Desafíos técnicos}
                \begin{center}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.58, every node/.style={transform shape},]
                
                        \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white, ,visible on=<{1,2,4}>
                                ] node[concept] {Desafíos Técnicos}
                        [clockwise from=150]
    
                        child[concept color=green!50!black,visible on=<{2,4}>] {
                            node[concept] {Tamaño de la red}
                                [clockwise from=-90]
                                child { node[concept] {Concurren\-cia operaciones} 
                                    [clockwise from=210]
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Max. throrughput}}
                                }
                                child { node[concept] (bulk) {Operacio\-nes \emph{bulk}} 
                                    [clockwise from=210]
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Max. throrughput}}
                                }
                                child { node[concept] {Distribu\-ción} 
                                    [clockwise from=150]
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Reducir carga cómputo}}
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Reducir tráfico}}
                                }
                        }
                        child[concept color=cyan!60!black,visible on=<{1,2,4}>] {
                            node[concept] {Características de aplicaciones}
                                [clockwise from=150]
                                child { node[concept] {Basadas en transacciones} 
                                    [clockwise from=150]
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Heteroge\-neidad equipos}}
                                }
                                child { node[concept] (a) {Basadas en interrupciones} 
                                    [clockwise from=150]
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Correla\-ción de alarmas}}
                                }
                                child { node[concept] {Basadas en cómputo} 
                                    [clockwise from=30]
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Capaci\-dad de cálculo}}
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Grandes datasets}}
                                }
                        }
                        child[concept color=yellow!60!black, visible on=<4>] {
                            node[concept] {Integración}
                                [clockwise from=30]
                                child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Swivel-chair syndrome} 
                                }
                        };
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                \end{center}
                \only<3>{
                        \includegraphics[scale=.6]{concurr12.png}
                }
        
            \end{frame}
        
\end{document}
```

The PNG file of slide `3`:

[image]

To show step-by-step, I am using the solution in previous post of [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step).

The problem is that slide 3 has the mindmap, and the `concurr12.png` image is placed below.
I would like to insert slides 3, 4, 6, and 7 with figures like `concurr12.png` in the same beamer frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning with `remember picture, overlay`.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=7}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shadows} 
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step
\tikzset{ 
    invisible/.style={opacity=0.1},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }
%%%---------------
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%---------------------
% \usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{standalone}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=7}
\begin{document}
            \begin{frame}[t]{Desafíos técnicos}
                \begin{center}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.58, every node/.style={transform shape},]
                
                        \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white, ,visible on=<{1,2,4}>
                                ] node[concept] {Desafíos Técnicos}
                        [clockwise from=150]
    
                        child[concept color=green!50!black,visible on=<{2,4}>] {
                            node[concept] {Tamaño de la red}
                                [clockwise from=-90]
                                child { node[concept] {Concurren\-cia operaciones} 
                                    [clockwise from=210]
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Max. throrughput}}
                                }
                                child { node[concept] (bulk) {Operacio\-nes \emph{bulk}} 
                                    [clockwise from=210]
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Max. throrughput}}
                                }
                                child { node[concept] {Distribu\-ción} 
                                    [clockwise from=150]
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Reducir carga cómputo}}
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Reducir tráfico}}
                                }
                        }
                        child[concept color=cyan!60!black,visible on=<{1,2,4}>] {
                            node[concept] {Características de aplicaciones}
                                [clockwise from=150]
                                child { node[concept] {Basadas en transacciones} 
                                    [clockwise from=150]
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Heteroge\-neidad equipos}}
                                }
                                child { node[concept] (a) {Basadas en interrupciones} 
                                    [clockwise from=150]
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Correla\-ción de alarmas}}
                                }
                                child { node[concept] {Basadas en cómputo} 
                                    [clockwise from=30]
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Capaci\-dad de cálculo}}
                                    child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Grandes datasets}}
                                }
                        }
                        child[concept color=yellow!60!black, visible on=<4>] {
                            node[concept] {Integración}
                                [clockwise from=30]
                                child[concept color=red!50!black] { node[concept] {Swivel-chair syndrome} 
                                }
                        };
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                \end{center}
                \only<3>{
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{concurr12.png}};}                                 }
        
            \end{frame}
        
\end{document}
```

[image: presentation with correct position of image]