# How to add optional arguments to tikz command

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-qtree

I used the code for adding overlay animations on `tikz-qtree` diagrams, suggested by Ignasi ([tex.SE answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117309/step-by-step-revealing-of-tikz-tree-using-opacity-trick-and-overlays-in-beamer)). With this code, I can create the following animations:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\tikzset{% add overlay animations to qtrees
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
        \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            
            \Tree
            [.\node [visible on=<1->] {Root};
                \edge [visible on=<2->];\node [visible on=<2->] {Leaf 1};
                \edge [visible on=<3>];\node [visible on=<3>] {Leaf 2};
            ]

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, I don't know how to modify the code to allow for two arguments to the `visible on` command to produce something like this:

```
[visible on=<1,5-6>]
```

When I add a second (optional) argument to the command, I get an error that says "File ended while scanning use of \pgfkeys@code." How can I modify the code to allow for the optional second argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `,` in the value given to a key needs to be protected from the parser.

In this special case, the best would be

```
[visible on=<{1,5-6}>]
```

Usually

```
[visible on={<1,5-6>}]
```

would be good to go, too but the `visible on` style does the same mistake, it should be

```
visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}}
```

but even the [`overlay-beamer-styles` library](https://ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) makes the same mistake.

Though, I would use a `@alt` style that expects two or three braced arguments and an `alt` key that expects one `<…>` and then one or two groups.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style args={<#1>}{@alt={#1}{}{invisible}},
    alt/.style args={<#1>#2#3}{@alt={#1}{#2}{#3}},
    @alt/.code n args={3}{\alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.\node [visible on=<1->] {Root};
    \edge [visible on=<2->];
      \node [visible on=<2->] {Leaf 1};
    \edge [visible on=<3>];
      \node [visible on={<1,5-6>}, alt=<{1,6}>{green}] {Leaf 2};
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is great! Thanks :)