# Beamer visible for a certain number of slides

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am creating a tikz picture that I want a certain component to be visible in a certain number of slides, say slides 1 and 3 only. I want the node to be invisible on page 2.

Is it possible?

I tried something like

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (abc) [decision, align=left, visible on=<1,3>] {abc};
\node (def) [decision, right of=abc, align=left, invisible on=<2>] {def};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but this does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please do not post a snippet but a Minimal Working Example. (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: [Q638552](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/638552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the `,` from confusing the handler for the optional arguments by wrapping your overlay specification in `{...}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=left, visible on=<{1,3}>] (abc) at (0,0) {abc};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]